# Code-generator with unique characters

Tags: code-challenge, code-generation

## Challenge

Your task is to write a piece of code that outputs another piece of code. That code must in turn output yet another code until the final code outputs the integer **1**. The chain ends the first time **1** is outputted.

**None of your programs may share any characters** (there's one exception in the Rules-section).

The winning submission will be the submission with the longest chain. The tie-breaker will be shortest total code-length.

---

#### Rules:

- You may use both functions, programs and snippets. You may assume a REPL environment.
- All functions must be written in the same language
- Symbol independent languages are disallowed. This includes partially symbol independent languages such as Headsecks.
- Default output formatting may optionally be disregarded in a function's output. This includes trailing newlines, `ans =` etc.
- You may reuse the space character (ASCII code point 32), but note the following:

  - You may use as many space characters as you like in one of the functions, but restrict it to maximum 5 in all other functions
  - You may not reuse any characters if code point 32 is not space in your language.
- None of the programs may take input
- The chain must be at least two programs long.

---

#### Example:

Your initial code is `abc+cab+bac`. This outputs: `foofoo*123`, which in turn outputs `disp(~0)`, which outputs `1`. This is a chain of 3 programs, with a combined length of 29 (tie breaker).

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/163607/76162)

Comment: [Somewhat related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/124362/how-high-can-you-count/)

Comment: To make sure I understood: the programs may use comments, right? I mean, parts of code that are "useless"

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes... I'm curious to see how that will help you though :)

Comment: @StewieGriffin Not much really :-) It only makes code length arbitrarily large, but it doesn't seem to help in extending the number of chain links

Comment: If the language prints strings with quotation marks, can the next program just contain the string without the quotes, or does the next program always have to be literally the entire output of the previous one?

Comment: Is it ok if we cannot prove or disprove the chain will eventually output a 1?

Comment: @Rzu You must prove that it will output 1 in the end.

Comment: @ngm quotes must be included.

Comment: The output of each program should be a string (or equivilant), yes? For example, `lambda:lambda:1` isn't valid since it returns an function?

Comment: Are simple expressions allowed? For example, could the final link of a Python program be `2^3`, which would just evaluate to `1`, or does it have to be e.g. `lambda:2^3`, `print(2^3)`, etc.?

Comment: If a function/snippet returns a string, are the string contents considered to be the code? The current top Java 8 answer uses this fact.

Comment: May the programs share boilerplate, such as `int main()` and the like?

Comment: In languages where literals can be programs (such as in a lot of the golfing langs), can `1` be both a program and the output of that program or does the chain end when `1` is the output?

Comment: @nneonneo simple expressions are allowed. That's what is meant by allowing "snippets".  Have a look at [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/124367/31516) answer to another challenge. Such answers are allowed.

Comment: @Emigna the chain ends when `1` is the output.

Comment: @ollien stuff like [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/124752/31516) and [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/124731/31516) is valid. Does that answer the question?

Comment: Exactly what output types are allowed for a language that has strings? Just strings, or would an array of bytes/chars/code points be allowed?

Comment: @Jakob everything that can be copied and use as code directly.

Comment: Probably because it's very very hard. Until someone comes along and posts one with 12 programs. :-)

Comment: Are we allowed to count the output `1.0` as part of the chain, since you state "_Default output formatting may **optionally be disregarded** in a function's output._"? So `ABC` -> `1.0` -> `1` (chain of 2)? (What if I don't want to _disregard_ it to improve the amount of chains.)

Comment: That's what optionally means :-) `X -> 1.0 -> 1` may count as 2. `X -> 1-> 1` counts as 1. Note that the final output should be `1`, not `1.0`.

Answer (score 18):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5-chain: 236 + 29 + 13 + 3 + 1 = 282 bytes

```
10101100011010001101100010110110001111000111001110101001000000000010111100100110011011010110011000100110101001001101100001110001111010100100000100010010001010011101011001110001000001011010101111001110011110001010111100001110110C₁<Au¦н.V
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f0AAIDQ0MQASMAtMIliGMghBgdSARKDCEqgBLwwwwhLFh4jBdMFMNDBGGI5kI0wAxF26hIVw93EoDQ4TNUAKmC8qEaDY0cH7U1GjjWHpo2YW9emH//wMA)

which prints the program

```
633693S<J6bαð3<žQTÌ>è9663тαhJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS4A0f8wNWFiMWX//zYzMzY5M1M8SjZizrHDsDM8xb5RVMOMPsOoOTY2M9GCzrFoSv//)

which prints the program

```
522472 2-255B
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f1MjIxNxIwUjXyNTU6f9/AA)

which prints the program

```
88ç
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fwuLw8v//AQ)

which prints the program

```
X
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/4v9/AA)

which prints `1`

Comment: `8784>žxB` and I'm probably KO'd. The lack of numbers for base conversion is a total crapshoot unless you calc it. The goal, if you want to beat emigna, is use the least amount of unique numbers per iteration. His answer reigns supreme because of the 88 in the second to last iteration. Truly a great answer.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn: We could easily free up `10` and make something in binary. But I don't know if we can generate the first program from binary without `B`.

Comment: I'll try again tonight to beat you, but if I don't I'm giving you the bounty. Doesn't seem like many are interested (or able (including me)).

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn: Your task may be a bit harder as I believe I have a 5-chain ;)

Comment: [Oh you](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/facebook/000/010/390/pC8jf5t4eWCDKcMu.jpg)... beautiful human being. Guess I'll still take a whack at it. I can at least post a 4 chain if it isn't close.

Comment: I'm just going to assume this KO'd me, I only have 2 hours tonight. If I find a 6 chain you owe me a bounty ;P

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn: I'll be happy to :) This was a very fun challenge!

Comment: Congrats for getting the 5th chain!

Answer (score 12):

## Java 8, chain of 2 functions, <s>90+10</s> <s>37+4</s> 28+4 = 32 bytes

```java
o\u002D\u003E"\44\55\76"+2/2
```

Which is equivalent to:

```java
o->"$->"+2/2
```

-57 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LY1BD4IwDIXv/IqG04gRCYIeiDc9ysXEi/NQB5rhGIR1JMbw2@eIJH1N2r7Xr8ER1031dkKhMXBGqb8BgNRUD08UNZTzCHChQeoXCHbtZAVjVPjt5OXLEJIUUIKGA7iO2yRJj3PfnkKeZTzP@X4XrtJN6orA@3v7UN6/xMb5X@ux7I@43QGjhfkxVLdxZynu/YmYjgXTVqlowU/uBw)

Which returns the String:

```java
$->1
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LY2xDsIwDET3foUHhmRoJOYK/oAulVgqBpMGlJK6VeNGQqjfHlyodB7unXzXY8Ky717ZBowRLujpUwB4Yjc/0DqoN/sDYNV19B0kXQla5USRkb2FGghOkA/l@ZirQvi03IPwPU7b3yDdquHZ07O9Aep/cfOO7AYzLmwmiViRsYqWEPQ@s@Yv)

Which returns the integer:

```java
1
```

Comment: [`\u0076\u002D\u003E\u0022\u0076\u002D\u003E\u0022+(3\u002D2)`](https://tio.run/##dY4xC8IwEIX3/oobE8RSUtChuOloF8FFHWJaJTVNS3MpiPS3x4vtKtw97t7Bu6@Ro1w31SsoI52Do9T2kwBoi/XwkKqGMq4AJxy0fYJi505XMPKC3ImayqFEraAECzsIV59l201UsY@aH36z@OevWD6bgociobje3w3FLaljfNcSFZsJLjeQfEF6O6zbtPOY9nRCZlPFrDeGL3RT@AI) (59 bytes+4 bytes). The rules says "None of your programs may share any characters", so `v->1` is valid because the final `1` isn't a program.

Comment: [39 bytes + 4 bytes](https://tio.run/##VU69CsIwEN59isMpQaylgg7FTUe7CC7qcKZVUtO0NJeCSJ89XrCLcD/cd3w/NQ64rMtXUAadgyNq@5kBaEtV/0BVQRFPgBP12j5BiXOrSxhkzujIzeUISSsowMIOAl59mmb7ONeHeVzbzR@0ENkqkyGfMbXzd8PUSWGI0g0nED@3yw1QTvZvR1WTtJ6Sjl8kbKKE9cbIKckYvg)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I knew `v->1` returning 1 is valid, but in my original answer `\u0031` would contain a 1, and `v->1` would then contain a 1 as well. Nice combination of both unicode Java and regular Java, though. And I golfed 2 more by changing `(2/2)` to `2/2`. (PS: There is also already a chain-3 Java answer by _Jakob_.)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Correction, I've been able to golf it to 28+4 by using `"\44\55\76"` instead of `"\u0076\u002D\u003E"`

Comment: Nice golfing on top of mine ;) I haven't checked the 3-chain answer yet. I'll do it right now.

Comment: I think that the 3-chain answer is invalid, unfortunately. Can you double-check my reasoning please?

Comment: What a beauty 

Comment: I want to give this more than +1, but I already bountied another D:

Answer (score 10):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 3-chain 198 + 44 + 3 bytes

```r
`+`=`\143\141\164`;+"\143\141\164\050\151\156\164\124\157\125\164\146\070\050\143\050\070\070\055\071\055\071\054\071\071\071\055\070\070\071\055\070\055\070\054\070\070\055\071\055\071\051\051\051"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYyxDcAwCAR3cesGEsBFlE0omCH7S4SAbLlK8TruBTzu1u02RTojqChkV2@7KzAocsws6XhEeAS5nERhQO3F3cf07DiIG6k4k/3c33yRfn6tNPcX)

Returns :

```r
cat(intToUtf8(c(88-9-9,999-889-8-8,88-9-9)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRCMzryQkP7QkzUIjWcPCQtdS11LH0tJS18ICiHUtdCBCmpqa//8DAA)

Returns :

```r
F^F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/3y3O7f9/AA)

Returns `1`

**Explanation :**

The first program is almost totally written in octal representation, where each character is written as `\xxx` where `xxx` is the ASCII code in octal mode. In human readable form would be :

```r
`+`=`cat`;+"cat(intToUtf8(c(88-9-9,999-889-8-8,88-9-9)))"
```

Here, to avoid the use of round brackets we redefine the prefix operator `+` equal to `cat` function, then we use that to print the next string. Even after assigning `cat` to `+`, the latter still keeps its prefix operator "status" and will just take whatever follows it as its first parameter.

The second program, simply prints the characters `F^F` obtaining them from decimal ASCII : `70,94,70`

Since in the first program we used the octal representation, only numbers `8` and `9` are free to be used; hence, we obtain `70` and `94` with some differences between numbers with only `8's` and `9's`.

Finally, the last program, `F^F`, exploits the `^` function (power of) which coerces `FALSE` to `0` and computes `0^0` returning `1`

Credits to :

- @ngm for the first 2-chain idea
- @Giuseppe for the hint to use octals in functions
- @BLT and @JayCe for the idea to override `+` in order to avoid brackets

---

Previous version :

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 2-chain <s>27+3</s> 24 + 2 bytes

```r
cat(intToUtf8(c(49,76)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRCMzryQkP7QkzUIjWcPEUsfcTFNT8/9/AA)

Returns:

```r
1L
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/39Dn/38A)

Returns `1`.

Comment: Nice one! Is `cat` mandatory?

Comment: `cat` is the shortest way to get rid of quotes. `write("1+F","")` and `substitute(1+F)` will also print without quotes, but they all have the letter `t` in them so I can't think of a way to get a chain of 3. I'm just happy for any `R` answer in a code-generation challenge!

Comment: I just saw that you asked in the comments whether quotes have to be removed. and the answer is yes :(. Maybe @Giuseppe will be able to come up with a magic solution? I am stuck too.

Comment: `cat(intToUtf8(c(48,94,48)))` uses only 3 different digits and returns `0^0`

Comment: And `eval(parse(t="foobar"))` also as a `t`... agree with you, it's great to see an `R` answer I just wish there was a way to expand it :)

Comment: `eval(parse(,,"foobar"))` does the same without a `t`. But now there's the `a`. There's also `bquote` which still doesn't help.

Comment: Well potentially you could have an output as a string with `"wri\164e"(function args)` to avoid a `t` or other similar encodings

Comment: I can't think how is possible to do better than 2-chain in R because of the necessity of round brackets... I mean, the default print method returns values with quotes, so you need at least cat/message at the first step, and then in the next ones you won't be able to use brakets anymore and therefore no functions as well...

Comment: @Giuseppe @digEmAll According to the latest comments to the question [`cat(intToUtf8(c(49,76)))`](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRCMzryQkP7QkzUIjWcPEUsfcTFNT8/9/AA) would work and is a bit shorter. Doesn't expand the chain though.

Comment: @digEmAll See BLT's comment to [my answer to another challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168660/80010)... I think there might be something here.

Comment: @JayCe: Maybe [this](https://tio.run/##fYzBCoMwEETv@QwvRjSQ2KxJKL36Be1tKSnSghcFCfTz0zWprVDowmPY2dlZYvS1P3lU@kAoVJ32x7ogNUSLCpJHN0AJMu/QZa8lgHItvDMdSiNzjvpWTXvy6N@oneqsG8nf8rv9o/pP1wZltMmAKhgbboGXOInv4FRWjD2XMdz5OIXzfAkPywdurXDCNc45YS0hbJOtqmrK9SVV/RT1156tE@ML "R – Try It Online") ?

Comment: @digEmAll wow. We have a length 3 chain.

Comment: [A little shorter 198+44+3](https://tio.run/##fYxBCsIwEEX3PUY3TWgDGU3SCeK2J9DdIJGC4CYFyf3jmNDajQY@L@8zM6@cQx/OgcAcOUDgTDj17d5JW01g@W9dcThw7Mi01Y0jPeo6x3sfFi@dZcKOpnJN6df5nW80f25taZtmvifRUVTfR7GTtX/GdFmu6YFiFojKKz947xUiR@FQKynl7yvTbcr5DQ "R – Try It Online")

Comment: I've made this answer a Community Wiki. Please feel free to add this with a little explanation.

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 2-Chain, 7+44 = 51 bytes

```python
lambda:("7072696e74203"+`3-2`).decode("hex")
```

and

```python
print 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNykl0UpDydzA3MjM0izV3MTIwFhJO8FY1yhBUy8lNTk/JVVDKSO1QkmTq6AoM69EwfA/hE7T0PwPAA)

The base 16 code translates to `print 1`, which is returned by the anonymous function.

Answer (score 7):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 3 programs, Length 42 bytes

```matlab
char("``;8%79b/7%,,b"-5)
```

Outputs: `[[63 24]*2 '']`.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/OSOxSEMpIcHaQtXcMknfXFVHJ0lJ11Tz/38A)

```matlab
[[63 24]*2 '']
```

Outputs: `~0`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/OtrMWMHIJFbLSEFdPfb/fwA)

```matlab
~0
```

Outputs: `1`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f@/zuD/fwA)

Answer (score 7):

## Perl 5, 3-chain, <s>151</s> 139 chars (114 + 20 + 5)

```
&{"CORE::SYSWRITe"|"CORE::39372!4"}(STDOUT,"\x70\x72\x69\x6E\x74\47\x50\x42\x5A\3\22\47\x5E\47\43\43\43\43\43\47")
```

The ugliness inside the `&{ }` evaluates to `CORE::syswrite`, and so the hex-escaped string is printed to standard output as:

```
print'PBZ^C^R'^'#####'
```

Please note that the *^C* and *^R* in the above represent literal control characters. (And not to be confused with the literal `^` caret that occurs between the two strings.)

This program in turn outputs:

```
say 1
```

Answer (score 6):

## Cjam, 4-chain, 28+20+3+1=52 bytes

#### Snippet 1:

```
"tugshrm\x18$\x18vj\x1b\x07um~l$\x1b"{71^}%
```

#### Snippet 2:

```
32 4/5*_c_1-\@2*9+c\
```

#### Snippet 3:

```
'Y(
```

#### Snippet 4:

```
X
```

Which then prints 1.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/#cjam)

***Note:***

1. Since Cjam *does not* have interpretation for escape characters, the ones in snippet 1 are only there for better web view. You need to use the corresponding actual characters to run the snippet.
2. If I cannot shave off more characters, then good job to @Emigna for the `05AB1E` answer!

Comment: In snippet 2 you've reused the character `1` used in snippet 1

Comment: See my note please. The escape characters are for the reader's convenience, in Cjam there are no escape characters, or they would not translate into the characters you think would in languages like C or python. When testing, you literally have to enter the characters manually instead of using the escape characters.

Answer (score 5):

## Excel, Chain 2, 27+3 bytes

```
=CHAR(45)&CHAR(45)&CHAR(49)
```

Not sure if this is OK...

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `CHAR(61)&` in the beginning as well for there to be a chain of 2?

Comment: You should use french instead of english (`CHAR` become `CAR`, 3 bytes saved), not sure if another language reduce it more

Comment: @Emigna But it seems typing `--1` in a cell and hit enter, it would just show `1` on the screen...

Comment: @tsh: Hmm, yeah it seems like Excel adds the `=` implicitly if you type `--1`.

Comment: Can you use `+1` instead of `--1`?

Comment: @Neil Excel does not insert a `=` mark for `+1` (but it does for `--1`), so I won't consider it as an expression. And I'm not sure if simply writing an `1` in the cell and call it "output 1" is valid. That's why `--1` is used.

Answer (score 5):

## x86 bytecode, Chain 2, 10+4 bytes

(Assembled with FASM, format PE)

`ÇA.Ï?¿<÷Y.` produces `1À@Ã` in the address next to it and executes it, which returns `1` in eax (as per fastcall).
In both cases the `.` actually represents `A` or LF.

In hex: `C7 41 0A CF 3F BF 3C F7 59 0A` and `31 C0 40 C3`.

Disassembled:

```
mov dword ptr ds:[ecx+A],3CBF3FCF
neg dword ptr ds:[ecx+A]
```

produces

```
xor eax,eax                      
inc eax                          
ret
```

This (ab?)uses the fact that the entrypoint of the program is stored in ecx, and then writes the inverse of the to be executed code to the address 10 bytes over and negates it.

May or may not break if assembled with anything but fasm, to anything but a PE or with a different entrypoint.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript REPL, lots of bytes, 4 iterate

```
(+!![]+[!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]))[(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]((!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]]+[])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+([][(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]()+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!![]])()([][[]]))[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]](![])[(+(!![]+!![]+[+[]]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([]+[])[([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]][([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+([]+(+[])[([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+!![]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]](!![]+!![]+!![]+[+[]])](([]+[])[([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]((!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]]+[])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+([][(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]()+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!![]])()(+[]+[![]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+(+[![]]+[][(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]())[+!![]+[+!![]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]][([][(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]()+[])[!![]+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[!![]+!![]]]([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]((!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]]+[])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]])()(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+!![]]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]((!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]]+[])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+([][(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]()+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!![]])()(![]+[![]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+([][(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]()+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![])+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+([][[]]+[])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]()[+!![]+[!![]+!![]]]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])))[([][(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]()+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]]([])
"\x60\44\x7b\55\x7e\x7b\x7d\x7d\44\x7b\55\x7e\x7b\x7d\x7d\x60\56\x73\x70\x6c\x69\x74\x60\x60\56\x74\x6f\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6e\x67\x60\x60"
`${-~{}}${-~{}}`.split``.toString``
1,1
1
```

Too lazy to optimize the JSFUCK code

## JavaScript REPL, 164 bytes, 3 iterate

may be able to expand

```javascript
[g=222222222222222222,e=2e40,f=2e23,f,2e40,n=2222e49,r=2e24,2e30,e,n,r,8e28,2e40,n,r,9e29,g].map(S=>String.fromCharCode(Math.log(S))).join([])
'\55\x7E\x7B\x7D'
-~{}
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU6xDoIwFNz5Edrk0WCBKAMOoqMTIzA0@CgQaEkhxsTor9dK3Lzc5XKXG24Qd7E0pp/XQOkb2karRY/IRi1JaUuZ8T8AZhzjEFpnPIIWtqS2JcYpmG8fuzYKAUGBgQPyw2/lUoo8BVmzScykyI7FanolWWv0lHfC5O4FuYq12y4UlFI26F6Rsqbg@VWSVI/9xenkdPbBC97PF3g7R1tT@wE)

Comment: @JoKing I didn't use `1` in other pros, so the first `1` is program and the 2nd one is result

Comment: Aren't you reusing the `{}`s?

Comment: @Neil Fixed and optimized

Comment: "The chain ends the first time 1 is outputted."

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 5 programs, 404+159+35+4+1 = 603 bytes

Getting to 4 programs was hard. 5 programs was *very hard!*

``````
'/'37 13+3+3+'3`/'37 13+3+3+77 13+37 13+3+3+'3`/'37 13+3+3+'3tttttttt`/'37 13+3+3+'3#'37 13+3+3+'3ttttt`'37 13+3+3+'3ttttt'37 13+3+3+77 13+'/'37 13+3+3+'3`<<tttttttttt'37 13+3+3+'3#'37 13+3+3+77 13+37 13+3+3+'3///<3////t````ttttt```<</////t`````t<3tttttttttt<3tt/'37 13+3+3+'3ttttttttt'37 13+3+3+'3`{'37 13+3+3+77 13+'y$'37 13+3+3+'3/////t`````ttI#I'77 13+3+'dk'hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh3_+''h
``````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X11f3dhcwdBYGwTVjROQueYQFi5pdeMSKEATVsZUlIAphGERulNsbErgAKf5mG7U19e3ARH6JQlAALE9AWiYPlwsocTGGGE0iI3dW6i2JlRjurhSRR3NargVJZ7KnupQ12mrp2SrZxABjOO11dUz/v8HAA)

```
,50],5W50],50qqqqqqqq],50 50qqqqq]50qqqqq5W,50]99qqqqqqqqqq50 5W50,,,90,,,,q]]]]qqqqq]]]99,,,,,q]]]]]q90qqqqqqqqqq90qq,50qqqqqqqqq50]x5Wv!50,,,,,q]]]]]qqF FZah
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X8fUIFbHNBxMGhRCAYitAOXGQmnTcJBSS8tCOACpAWrU0dGxBBE6hbFAANETC1SoAxeLLbQ0QGgDsZHsAhoTW2EaXqYINgmuo9BNwS0qMeP/fwA)

This might be my favorite program I've written on PPCG:

```
22 2 2**2-2-- 22Y2 2EEEEEEEEBPX)2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/38hIAQi1tIx0jXR1FYyMIoE8VyhwCojQNNJU@P8fAA)

```
84
c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/38KEK/n/fwA)

```
T
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P@T/fwA)

#### Explanation:

Having used hours on this program, I won't write the entire explanation now! I'll write it later!

Short summary:

```
T            -> Literal true = 1
```

---

```
84c          -> Convert 84 to its ASCII-character T
```

---

```
22 2 2**...  -> Calculate 84 using only 2, * and -
 22Y2        -> 22Y2 is a cell array with the name of all the months
 2EE..B      -> Is 512 in binary [1 0 0 ...]
 P           -> Flips is, [0 0 ... 1]
 X)          -> Uses the binary vector as index and gets the 10th element
             -> 'October'
2)           -> The second character, 'c'
             -> Resulting in the stack: 84, 'c' that's implicitly printed
```

---

```
,50]...      -> A string with ASCII character codes of '22 2...
             -> There's a lot of ,xyz], which means "do twice" and q which is decrement
```

In order to convert this to a string instead of character codes, we need to concatenate it with a string using `h`. To get a string, without using quotes, or the XY modifiers, we do base conversion and convert an integer to whitespace.

---

```
'/'37 13 ...  -> Concatenation of strings and character codes using only available numbers
3_+           -> Subtract 3 from all character codes to get the correct ones
''h           -> And concatenate with the empty string.
```

Answer (score 5):

## CJam, 7-chain, 92365+1819+79+14+9+3+1 bytes

[This 92365-byte program](https://tio.run/##7dhBjsIwEETRPRdBHAtlh8T9l@YGUYRsx65@c4Ayk/T/Xc7xeX9bez5eff@6Bw4LvhA46p85y7185j8/btjbGXNIz2chKyOrzsOgXMqlXFmUS9/0Td@rvnPTaTrtGlkehnJB3/RdyTU4xKEahWlMY9rVSJarEeVSbphyTafpVAhkKQTKBX3T92yafVfBIQ7VKFleuEpmFVgFKhkOcZjOoek0nS4MslwYlHz6pm8lH4c4VKMcimlMY1qWqxHlUi7lmk7TqRDIUgiUC/qm7/k0@66CQxyqUbK8cJXMKrAKVDIc4jCdQ9NpOl0YZLkwuDBYBVaBVSDLKqBv@qbvyTSHuAaHOFSjZKlRahR90/eq79x0mk67RpaHoVzQN337RoNDHKpRstQolcwqsApUMhziEIem03S6MMhyYVDy6Zu@lXwc4lCNciimMY1pWa5GlEu5lGs6TadCIEshUC7om75v0bfvKjjEYVaNwjSmMe1qJMsLp1zKTVGu6TSdCoEshUC5oG/69rkE05jGtA0ty8Ogb/qmb1naJB3R0drv3HSaTstSlodBuZRLubIol77pm77d50yn6bRrlAtZiopVYBWguZy@6YiO3JtMp@m0lGR5GJRLuZQri3Lpm77pe2uaQw7FNKYxLYuO6IiOVAxMY7oU06bTdNo4smpue1lWgVVgFciyCuibvuk7RN8hh2Ia05jGNKYx7ZrlUIfKsq6sK@uKtxzqUFmyZMlS/BQ/xc9KdygTMiETYhrTmMa0LA508@RmbuYHHOJQR5JFbWoUfdN3LX2rZJjGNKYxjWlMYxrTmMY0VKEKVajCC17wkuU2UOoNcDM3b@1mUnKoQ2XJkiVLIVVIFVIfCzbKau0H) prints

```
YaY+`$1<mR1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+YaY+`$1<mR1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+YaY+`$1<mRYaY+`$1<mR1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+YaY+`$1<mR11+11+YaY+`$1<mR1+11+11+YaY+`$1<mR1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+YaY+`$1<mRYaY+`$1<mR1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+YaY+`$1<mR11+11+YaY+`$1<mR1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+YaY+`$1<mR11+11+YaY+`$1<mRYaY+`$1<mR1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+YaY+`$1<mR11+11+YaY+`$1<mR1+11+11+YaY+`$1<mR1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+YaY+`$1<mRYaY+`$1<mR1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+YaY+`$1<mR11+11+YaY+`$1<mR1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+YaY+`$1<mR11+11+YaY+`$1<mRYaY+`$1<mR1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+YaY+`$1<mR1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+YaY+`$1<mR11+11+YaY+`$1<mR1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+YaY+`$1<mRYaY+`$1<mR1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+YaY+`$1<mR11+11+YaY+`$1<mR1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+YaY+`$1<mR11+11+YaY+`$1<mRYaY+`$1<mR1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+YaY+`$1<mR11+11+YaY+`$1<mR1+11+11+YaY+`$1<mR1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+YaY+`$1<mRYaY+`$1<mR1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+YaY+`$1<mR11+11+YaY+`$1<mR1+11+11+YaY+`$1<mR1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+YaY+`$1<mRYaY+`$1<mR1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+YaY+`$1<mR1+11+11+YaY+`$1<mR1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+YaY+`$1<mR1+1+1+1+1+11+YaY+`$1<mRYaY+`$1<mR1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+YaY+`$1<mR1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+YaY+`$1<mRYaY+`$1<mR1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+YaY+`$1<mR1+1+1+1+1+11+YaY+`$1<mRYaY+`$1<mR1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+YaY+`$1<mR1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+YaY+`$1<mR1+11+11+YaY+`$1<mR1+1+1+1+1+11+YaY+`$1<mR1+11+11+YaY+`$1<mRYaY+`$1<mR1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+YaY+`$1<mR1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+YaY+`$1<mR1+11+11+YaY+`$1<mR1+11+11+YaY+`$1<mR1+1+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+YaY+`$1<mR11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+YaY+`$1<mR1+1+11+11+11+11+YaY+`$1<mR1+11+11+YaY+`$1<mR1+1+1+1+1+11+11+1+1+YaY+`$1<mR11+11+YaY+`$1<mR1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+YaY+`$1<mR1+11+11+YaY+`$1<mR1+11+11+YaY+`$1<mR1+11+11+YaY+`$1<mR1+1+11+YaY+`$1<mR1+11+YaY+`$1<mR1+1+1+1+1+11+11+1+1+YaY+`$1<mR11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+YaY+`$1<mR1+1+1+1+1+
```

which prints

```
34 4673 4656 4673 4656 5464 4656 4673 4673 4740 34 50 34707 5477]{N7=64777-,=}%
```

which prints

```
";*;*Q*;;~"2f^
```

which prints

```
9(9(S(99|
```

which prints

```
88c
```

which prints

```
X
```

which prints `1`.

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, 10 programs, 5,751,122,990 bytes

I was too lazy to golf it... But apparently I don't need to golf it to be competitive. But without golfing it is a bit difficult to post the solution in an answer.

It should work in [the JavaScript interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/) in theory, but the program is too long to be tested in a browser. It should output the same in the Java interpreter except for the last program. But it may also run out of memory in the Java interpreter for the first few programs.

#### Statistics

```
5683631402 bytes, used )\_l
  65027874 bytes, used %&<>WXehrstu{|} and newline
   2247044 bytes, used +DEFHIS~
    199997 bytes, used ,38=[]`
     15352 bytes, used -25:N and space
      1181 bytes, used 67c
        84 bytes, used #'(@CKMTgkp
        21 bytes, used !"$?BJLQR^fijo
        16 bytes, used */4AGYZabdy
        19 bytes, used .09
         1 byte,  used 1
```

#### First bytes

```
l)__)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))...
\n{s}sX>X<eu{h}sX>X<eu{\n}sX>X<{{XXXXXXX}seeseeseeW>{X<{|}%}%}%{|}sX>X<{{X}se...
SH+~+E+E+E+SH+~+H+E~+SH+~+H+E~+SI+~+H+D+D+SI+~+I+E+E+SH+~+H+E~+SF+~+E+SD+~+D+...
[33]`3=,3333=[33]`3=,388333=[8]`88=,8333=[8]`88=,8333=[8]`88=,8338=[8]`88=,33...
N:--25--22- 2-N:--25--22- 2-N:--22--22-N:--25--22- 2-N:--25--22- 2-N:--22--22...
776776777767c677676676677667c66677666676776c776776777767c7667776c666776666767...
'#('@('T(('k(('T((('k(('K('p(''((('@('T(('k(('T((('k(('k('M('#(('#('C('g('g((...
"?RiQiJo$?RiQijL!"Bf^
4YbZbAd/4YbZbaG*
0.99999999999999999
1
```

`\n` is newline in the second program.

#### Generator

```
"'#('@('T(('k(('T((('k(('K('p(''((('@('T(('k(('T((('k(('k('M('#(('#('C('g('g((((((((("

{_[i1:X;{_1&6+ \1$X*X5*:X;- 2/}16*;]__,,:)\f<Wf%10fb:c@#)<W%'c}%s

"67c"
"N:--22--22-
N:--25--22- 2-
N:--55--25--5--2--2-"N/ers

"N:-25 "
"[33]`3=,3333=
[33]`3=,388333=
[8]`88=,8333=
[8]`88=,8338=
[8]`88=,333=
[8]`88=,88="N/ers

"[]`38=,"
"SH+~+E+E+E+
SI+~+H+D+D+
SI+~+I+E+E+
SH+~+H+E~+
SI+~+I+D~+H+E~+
SF+~+E+
SD+~+D+D~+"N/ers

"SDEFHI+~"
"{s}sX>X<eu
{t}sX>X<{{XXXXXXXX}s{X}s{XXXXXX}erseeW>{X<{&}%}%}%
{ee}sX>X<eu
{&}sX>X<{{XXXXXXs}s{X}s{XXXXXX}erseeW>{X<{|}%eu}%}%
{h}sX>X<eu
{h}sX>X<eu{X|}%
{N}sX>X<{{XXXXXXX}seeseeseeW>{X<{|}%}%}%
{|}sX>X<{{X}seeW>{X<{|}%}%}%"N/'Nf/Nf*erN\+s

1>"l)_"o)\{'_oi10-')*o'\o}/i10-')*o
```

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 2 chain, 15+2 = 17 bytes

```apl
⎕AV[2+⎕AV⍳'⍳.']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HfVMewaCNtMP2od7M6EOupx@KUAAA)

Outputs the program

```apl
*0
```

That outputs

```apl
1
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 2 functions, 31+4 = 35 bytes

```js
function(){return atob`Xz0+MQ`}
```

returns `_=>1`, which returns `1`

```js
f0 =
function(){return atob`Xz0+MQ`}

res0 = f0()
console.log('Output of 1st function:', res0)

f1 = eval(res0)
res1 = f1()
console.log('Output of 2nd function:', res1)
```

Comment: Wouldn't function invocation have to be part of each program?

Comment: @TehShrike Functions were explicitly allowed in the rules. (A function + its invocation code would be a full program. So, I don't think that would make much sense.)

Comment: Oh good call, I missed that 

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, 3 programs, 431 bytes

### Program 1, 332 bytes

A lambda from one (empty) parameter of any type to `String`.

```java
x\u002D\u003E"\151\156\164\40\157\75\70\46\70\52\70\54\156\75\53\53\157\53\70\73\156\145\167\40\123\164\162\151\156\147\50\51\53\50\143\150\141\162\51\50\47\171\47\53\157\51\53\50\143\150\141\162\51\50\47\54\47\53\157\51\53\50\143\150\141\162\51\50\47\75\47\53\157\51\53\156\53\50\143\150\141\162\51\50\47\56\47\53\157\51\53\156\73"
```

This is just a lambda with the arrow characters Unicode-escaped returning the text of the second program encoded with octal escape sequences.

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##lVFBa8MgFD7HXyE9JbCJJiYeuva0DXbYqce5g02TYJYaSUxZGf3t2dN2DMqgDPR9D9/3fU99rTqo@95Wpt19zHbadrrEZafGEb8qbfAXii6Ho1MOoNZGdbgFFZmc7kg9mdLp3pDnS/LwYlzVVMMd3rhBm2aNa7xC86ecKE0ffcyeFpLlDHYhWcElp5AKKXIpqOSFj3kaIg8cKOSZX54FABWRndU8BwcRHNIsmLEi/TXnwAcbFvTA4V7mkQWeL0BHIZlgHn5a3OTDxf5Dhwdc0/31bjUp/lSJbDEjFC3R9WQOvd7hPQwtPn/82ztWQzMmfobR5ji6ak/6yRELRRfXRFnbHWOaJEsUndBp/gY)

### Program 2, 93 bytes

Snippet producing a `String`.

```java
int o=8&8*8,n=++o+8;new String()+(char)('y'+o)+(char)(','+o)+(char)('='+o)+n+(char)('.'+o)+n;
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##XY5BDoIwEEXX5RRdSWuRdRPCEVyxNC4qVCzClLQFQwxnr0WIRleTN/9n5jViFAfdS2iqu@@HS6tKXLbCWnwUCvAzQtvSOuHCKJxRUOMroSHzChzWOd/xPU8gZ0wznhnpBgMY5GMrE8pIeROGkniKmf5S8kP5m@DD6cqZj9Ac/WuMWlW4C4Zk/XE6Y2Fqu0ghVEzWyS7Vg0v7EDoSbGm2nJn9Cw) (with return added)

### Program 3, 6 bytes

A lambda from one (empty) parameter of any type to `int`.

```java
z->9/9
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##XY0xD4IwFIRn@iveCIlWV4Iymjg4MRqHJ7SkWNqGvpKg4bfXmjA53Ze73N2AM@6tE2boXtGFp1YttBq9hxsqAx@WbaYnpCRSGdQwpBYPpDSXwbSkrOGXDU5XQ6IX0w42qEHCmcX3vi4PZWRZxf43Z6s6GNNd3tCkTH9/AE69L37vWbN4EiO3gbhLIeWSo3N6yY9FUbFsZWv8Ag)

Comment: Nice answer! You can golf `\166` to `\44` for -1 byte, since `$` is also a valid variable name. [Try it online](https://tio.run/##Lcy9DoMgFIbh3as4cYKhpk20Dl5DJ0fpcKq0wSoQOJg0hmun9Gf7kjffM@OGB2OlnqdnGhf0Hi6o9F4AeEJSI6SenNIPuDO@O0nB6VLUtWga0Z5Fe/qOY9nFBGDDbcmP/3EzaoI1Y@wnDFdA/oEB@pcnuVYmUGVzokWzzPMux1jE9AY), resulting in `$->9-8` ([Try it online.](https://tio.run/##Lc0xC8IwEIbhvb/iBocWbGal2lFwcCq4iMPZpiU1vYTmUijS3x5PcDv4Xp4bccHSeU1j906txRDghoY@GUBgZNPCKIWKbKzqI7VsHKnL/zjdnen2cCXWg55r6OGcdmV9LA@pykTw8WVF@EOLxDAJnjc8GxoeT8Di9wigWQPrSbnIysvEea/Qe7vmFK0tikqiLdvSFw))

Comment: After several tries, it's just not possible to make a 3-chain with Java. You **need** the `\uXXXX` in the first code to avoid `->`. Then you **need** either `return` (function) or `System.out` (snippet or function), both contain a `u` which you already used in `\uXXXX`. So I personally think this entry is invalid and I downvoted it accordingly.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Snippets are explicitly allowed in this challenge (first rule). In addition, `System.console().printf` could be used to prevent the use of `u`. [Something similar is done in this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90669/52210) and I've also used it [in these two answers of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A52210+System.console).

Comment: Thanks @KevinCruijssen but a snippet must still output. Here's a fix around all: `x->"\146\157\162\50\143\150\141\162\40\44\72\156\145\167\40\143\150\141\162\133\135\173\47\171\47\54\47\54\47\54\47\75\47\54\47\70\47\54\47\56\47\54\47\70\47\175\51\123\171\163\164\145\155\56\143\157\156\163\157\154\145\50\51\56\160\162\151\156\164\146\50\53\53\44\53\156\145\167\40\123\164\162\151\156\147\50\51\51\73"` (319 bytes) turns into `for(char $:new char[]{'y',',','=','8','.','8'})System.out.printf(++$+new String());` (89 bytes) turns into `z->9/9` (6 bytes). Total: 404 bytes.

Comment: I meant `System.console()` for the 2nd program, which is correctly 89 bytes (while the `System.out` makes it 83 bytes).

Comment: Hi folks. @OlivierGrégoire take a look at [this example](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/124367) that was [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/165518/?noredirect=1#comment400644_165518) by OP to show acceptable snippets. The second-last snippet neither returns nor prints its output.

Comment: Ok, I yield. Then this makes everything shorter: `var r=new String();for(char $:new char[]{'8','.','8'})r+=++$;` (61 bytes), and the first program can be as simple as `"..."` instead of encoding `->`.

Comment: Also, just for fun, you can reflectively get a reference to `System.out` without using `u`, which is what another, no-snippet, 3-chain of mine does.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>38 37 36</s>  35 bytes, Chain of 4

```
ØJiⱮ⁾ɱṾ⁽÷ṃ;ṾØJ⁽¡Ṡị
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wDK/MRxvXPWrcd3Ljw537HjXuPbz94c5mayAbKAXkHlr4cOeCh7u7//8HAA)** (**18** bytes)

```
8220,163,187Ọ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/CyMhAx9DMWMfQwvzh7p7//wE)**  (**13** bytes)

```
“£»
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5xDiw/t/v8fAA)** (**3** bytes)

```
!
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/x/38A)** (**1** byte)

**18+13+3+1=35** bytes

#### How?

```
ØJiⱮ⁾ɱṾ⁽÷ṃ;ṾØJ⁽¡Ṡị - Main Link: no arguments
    ⁾ɱṾ            - list of charcters -> ['ɱ','Ṿ']
ØJ                 - yield the characters of Jelly's code-page
   Ɱ               - Ɱap across the two characters applying:
  i                -   first index of? -> [163, 187]
       ⁽÷ṃ         - 8220 (a base 250 compressed number)
          ;        - concatenate -> [8220, 163 187]
           Ṿ       - un-eval (get Jelly code) -> "8220,163,187"
                   - (Note: here a full program prints 8220,163,187 as it is the end
                   - of a leading constant chain due to the following constant)
            ØJ     - yield the characters of Jelly's code-page
              ⁽¡Ṡ  - 1206 (a base 250 compressed number)
                 ị - index into (1-indexed & modular, so gets the 182nd item, 'Ọ')
                   - implicit print (making the final output 8220,163,187Ọ)

8220,163,187Ọ - Main link: no arguments
8220,162,187  - list of numbers -> [8220, 162, 187]
            Ọ - cast ordinals to characters -> ['“','£','»']
              - implicit print (flat Jelly lists print as if strings so outputs “£»)

“£» - Main link: no arguments
“   - open string-literal
 £  - the content of the string-literal
  » - close it interpreting as a compressed string
    - this yields ['!']
    - implicit print (outputs !)

! - Main link: no arguments
! - factorial (of implicit input 0 - 0! = 1 as it is the empty product)
  - implicit print (outputs 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 3 snippets, 68 + 12 + 3 = 83 bytes

```python
chr(44*2+4).join([chr(42&54),`45+25`,`42*2+52`,`4*4+55`+chr(42&54)])
```

which produces the string of octal literals:

```python
"\70\136\71"
```

which produces:

```python
8^9
```

Which finally produces `1`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/BasQgEIbveYppDqtuQqCil0BOS1@hl1JQUkMsaQyjbS1tnz2duAv14u/wfb/M9pXmsMo9wwB1Xe/jjFyps2yU6F6DX/lTmciTVqI1SjdSG7olEVoe6awarU3zTz2LnYq6mNBvXFSRiqNLlD5nvzjIcDeAuTd9BXQ29GuCXLKfIMKpwCTzLEQPaH108GiXd/eAGJCzS1inxY@ph@9f1k0B3yzxN48cUboi/Ay3SXkf6x2l7sMuPLfkElhdf2eX2aIdk8PD6FkLjF13jwGTe@GR2P0P)

Answer (score 2):

## SmileBASIC, chain 3, 375 bytes

```
k=59599-44444print c("sbanm",k,4,"")+c("sbwav",44-5,2,"")+c("sbwav",594-222,4,"")+c("game5vs",4528-442,2,"")+c("sbanm",k,4,"")+c("sbanm",72,5-4,"")*2+c("sbwav",594-222,4,"")+c(sbwav,854-44,2,"")+c("staffroll",259+2,9,"")+c("ex8techdemo",24455,5-2,"")+key(4)[.]def c(f,s,l,q)for i=.to-5+l+4q=q+load("txt:sys/"+f,.)[s+i]next:return q:end
```

Outputs:

```
CHR$63OUT A$CHR$33OUT B$PRINT A$;B$;L
```

Outputs:

```
?!0
```

Outputs:

```
1
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP 7.0, 2-chain, 35 + 8 = 43 bytes

While writing my initial answer I realized I could just use base64 encode the second echo. It shaved off 11 bytes, so here it is. You can find my original idea below, too.

#### Run using php -r:

```
echo base64_decode('RUNITyAxPz4=');
```

This outputs:

```
ECHO 1?>
```

Which then obviously prints:

```
1
```

#### Output:

[image: Code run with additional && echo for readability]
*My code when run in a terminal. The appended **&& echo** is for readability only.*

#### Comments:

There's not much to it really. Very simple once you know about "?>" implicitly acting as ";".  The "tricky" part was to figure out what to encode:

- *ECHO 1;* became *RUNITyAx**O**w==*, so we have a collision of uppercase O's. No good.
- *echo 1;* became *ZWN**o**byAxOw==*, so now there's two *lower*case o's. Unfortunate!
- *ECHO 1?>* became *RUNITyAxPz4=*. It's the same length and none of the characters collide. So that's it!

#### Alternatively we can use "echO" and "ECHo", too (36 + 7 = 43 bytes).

```
echO base64_decOde('RUNIbyAxOw==')?>
ECHo 1;
1
```

We can also switch the ; and ?> around using that. It works equally well and it all scores the same in length.

---

---

### My initial solution:

## PHP 7.0, 2-chain, 44 + 10 = 54 bytes

This is the best I could come up with at first. I understood that "unique characters" meant "echo" is not equal to "ECHO". Hope I got that right!

#### Run using php -r:

```
echo strtoupper(urldecode('echo true%3b'))?>
```

This outputs:

```
ECHO TRUE;
```

Which in turn gives us our number:

```
1
```

#### Output:

[image: Code run with additional && echo for readability]
*My code when run in a terminal. The appended **&& echo** is for readability only.*

#### Some comments:

- I think you can only do a 2-chain in PHP since it requires the ";" instruction separator.

  - You can get around this *once* by using "?>", which implies a semicolon, but obviously can't re-use it a second time
  - This was the hardest part for me to figure out. I didn't know this worked beforehand, nor that "?>" was even allowed when running via php -r
- By using strtoupper() I was able to just write the code for chain #2 in lowercase, while the output is obviously uppercase. Easy mode right there!
- urldecode() allows me to encode ";" as "%3b"
- That's all there is really, nothing too exciting

---

Thanks for the challenge, I learned something today!

Answer (score 2):

## Lua, 2 chain, 83+8=91 bytes

```
load(('').char(0x70,0x72,0x69,0x6E,0x74,39,0x70,0x72,0x69,0x6E,0x74,34,49,34,39))()
```

Outputs

```
print"1"
```

Which outputs

```
1
```

Answer (score 1):

## Charcoal, 2 programs, 10 + 2 = 12 bytes

```
⭆´Ｇ´·℅⊕⊕℅ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///R2rZDW97vWX5oy6Htj1paH3VNBaGW1nM7//8HAA) Outputs

```
Ｉ¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9npWHdv7/DwA) Which outputs 1.

Answer (score 1):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 2 chain, 9 + 2 = 11 bytes

```
72-_#23-@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@//f3Eg3XtnIWNfh/38A)

This outputs

```
5/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@//fVP//fwA)

(Plus some default output which can be ignored per OP's rules)

This in turn outputs

```
1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), 2 chain, 31 + 3 = 34 bytes

Snippet 1:

```
(`X.Z`/"")|ord _|push _+3|chr _
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8pPSfyfm5iZV/1fIyFCLypBX0lJsya/KEUhvqagtDhDIV7buCY5o0gh/n/tfwA)

Snippet 2:

```
[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8pPSfyfm5iZV/0/2jD2f@1/AA)

They are snippets, because every valid Röda program must include `main{...}` bloat. They are also valid Röda REPL programs.

Answer (score 1):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 3 programs, 48 bytes

First:

```
82 2-adAArdAAI2*-rAAI-I2/2^-f
```

Yields the second:

```
75
P
90
P
110
P
```

Yields the third:

```
KZn
```

Yields `1`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/9/CSMFINzHF0bEIiD2NtHSLgJSup5G@UZxuGhdXsqFBgIJyck5qYpFCWn6RQl5qRYlCQWZqcqpCfppCckZiZp4VF5e5KVcAl6UBkDA0BJFEavOOyvv/HwA) (has some stack-clearing and newline-printing code thrown in to make all three bits run in one go).

Perhaps best to start at program three, `KZn`. There are only a few ways to print things in `dc`, and I realized at this stage I would probably be stuck with either `p` or `n`, both of which are in the 100s in decimal ASCII. This means that I was almost certainly going to have to generate 1 instead of just using the program `1n`. `K` pushes the current (default: 0) precision to the stack, and `Z` pushes the number of digits of top-of-stack, which gives us the 1 to print.

The second program is pretty straightforward. `P` prints the character with the given ASCII value, so we print `75` (`K`) `90` (`Z`) and finally `110` (`n`), which works wonderfully. It also means that, aside from the aforementioned 1, I can't use the digits 5, 7, 9, or 0 elsewhere. I also need a method other than `P` for turning numbers into characters.

The first program, then, has to make four numbers without using the digits 1, 5, 7, 9, or 0. It needs to make **`80`** (ASCII value of `P`): `82 2-`; **`75`**: `AA` (110) `I-` (subtract the default input radix, 10) `I2/` (so, 5) `2^` (so, 5^2, 25) `-` (75); **`90`**: `AA` (110) `I2*` (twice the default input radix of 10, so 20) `-` (90); and **`110`**: well, it's just `AA`. After making `80`, we use `a` to convert a number to a string. There are some `r`everse and `d`uplicate commands in there to put the `P`s in the right spots, and then finally we print the whole stack with `f`.

I'm pretty sure I didn't screw this up, but I did have my head spinning a little bit...

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 + 3 = 8 bytes

```
ght<n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/PaPEJu//fwA)

which right off the bat returns

I am taking the output 1.0 as not equalling 1, so I run that code:

```
1.0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fUM/g/38A)

which returns

```
1
```

And there you go!

Number of programs = `2`

Comment: Welcome to PPCG.

Comment: I just tried to write random things and see what i get. Also, one might use a turing machine program.

Comment: You can remove the `h` (convert to hexadecimal). The `g` (get length, default 0) with `t` (square-root) already gives a decimal `0.0`. With `<` (decrease by 1) it becomes `-1.0` and then `n` (square) changes this into `1.0`. You could also replace the `<n` with `>` (increase by 1). ;) So in total it's 3 bytes (`gt>`). Alternatively you could use `Xt` (`1` and square-root). PS: I'm not sure if `1.0` to `1` is a valid part of the chain. I've asked OP to verify. Welcome to PPCG and enjoy your stay.

Comment: well, computers process the string '1.0' differently than '1'.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 2-chain, 24+3 = 27 bytes

```
$><<(''<<56+56<<' '<<49)
```

Output is

```
p 1
```