# Alternating Fibonacci

Tags: code-golf, number, fibonacci

In the alternating Fibonacci sequence, you first start with `1` and `1` as usual.

However, instead of always adding the last two values to get the next number, you alternate starting with adding, and every other time you subtract instead.

The sequence starts like this:

```
1
1
2    # 1 + 1
-1   # 1 - 2
1    # 2 + -1
-2   # -1 - 1
-1   # 1 + -2
-1   # -2 - -1
-2   # -1 + -1
1    # -1 - -2
-1   # -2 + 1
2    # 1 - -1
1    # -1 + 2
1    # 2 - 1
```

etc.

<sup>Notice that after it starts over once it gets to `1` and `1` again.</sup>

Given a number *N*, print the *N*th term of the alternating fibonacci sequence.

Remember, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the code with the smallest number of bytes wins.

Comment: Is the sequence 0-indexed or 1-indexed (or either one)?

Comment: @Doorknob Either one. Specify in your answer.

Comment: Can we return `true` for `1`?

Comment: Do the first two `1` values count as initial values for the output? Or do we start directly with the `2`?

Comment: @LuisMendo The first two count.

Answer (score 17):

## JavaScript (ES6), 25 bytes

```
n=>"334130110314"[n%12]-2
```

0-indexed. You can shorten the string with a slightly recursive version, though it adds 6 bytes:

```
f=n=>"3341301"[n]-2||f(13-n%12)
```

This is still shorter than the definitive recursive formula:

```
f=n=>n<2||f(n-2)+f(n-1)*(-n%2|1)
```

Answer (score 8):

### Python, 31 bytes

```python
lambda n:2-33107256/5**(n%12)%5
```

Doesn't bother trying to compute the value. Just looks in up in the peroidic length-12 list `[1, 1, 2, -1, 1, -2, -1, -1, -2, 1, -1, 2]`, which is compressed in base 5.

Compare to a recursive solution (37 bytes) with `True`'s for 1:

```python
f=lambda n:n<2or(-1)**n*f(n-1)+f(n-2)
```

or to string storage

```python
lambda n:int('334130110314'[n%12])-2
```

or an attempt at an arithmetical expression.

```python
lambda n:4**n%7%3*(-1)**((n+n%2*4)/6)
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Oasis](http://github.com/Adriandmen/Oasis), 10 bytes

Reminds me to implement some more built-ins :p. The input is **0-indexed**.

Code:

```
n>2%x<*c+V
```

Translated version:

```
a(n) = (2*((n+1)%2)-1) * a(n-1) + a(n-2)
a(1) = 1
a(0) = 1
```

And calculates the *n*th term.

[Try it online!](http://oasis.tryitonline.net/#code=bj4yJXg8KmMrVg&input=&args=NQ)

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
•É&Â†º•sèÍ
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCiw4kmw4LigKDCuuKAonPDqMON&input=NQ)

Comment: I think I should start learning 05AB1E instead of Jelly.

Answer (score 4):

## Jelly, 12 bytes

```
“½Ġ⁻S’b5_2⁸ị
```

**[TryItOnline!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCcwr3EoOKBu1PigJliNV8y4oG44buL&input=&args=NA)**

1-based, given the first and second values are `1`.

Not sure if this is shorter yet, but for this I noted that the series has a period of 12:
`[1, 1, 2, -1, 1, -2, -1, -1, -2, 1, -1, 2]`

So, I took that and added `2` to give
`[3, 3, 4, 1, 3, 0, 1, 1, 0, 3, 1, 4]`
then converted that as a base `5` number to base `250`, to give:
`[11, 197, 140, 84]`
(which is `184222584`).

```
“½Ġ⁻S’b5_2⁸ị - Main link: n
“½Ġ⁻S’       - base 250 number      184222584
      b5     - convert to base 5   [3, 3, 4, 1, 3, 0, 1, 1, 0, 3, 1, 4]
        _2   - subtract 2          [1, 1, 2, -1, 1, -2, -1, -1, -2, 1, -1, 2]
          ⁸  - left argument, n
           ị - index into (1-based and modular)
```

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth - 13 bytes

Base encoded once cycle series, modular indexed.

```
@-R2jC"
ûx"5
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%40-R2jC%22%0A%C3%BB%03x%225&input=5&debug=0).

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, <s>33</s> 26 bytes

```haskell
a!b=a:b:(a+b)!(-a)
(1!1!!)
```

Recursive approach. 0-indexed. [Try it on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/90QKI3)
Saved 7 bytes thanks to [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor).

Usage:

```haskell
Prelude> (1!1!!)11
2
```

Comment: Looks shorter to just do `a!b=a:b:(a+b)!(-a)`.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>17</s> <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
'"Bl)e'F5Za2-i)
```

Input is 1-based.

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=JyJCbCllJ0Y1WmEyLWkp&input=MTA)

#### Explanation

The sequence has period `[1 1 2 -1 1 -2 -1 -1 -2 1 -1  2]`.

```
'"Bl)e     % Compressed array [1 1 2 -1 1 -2 -1 -1 -2 1 -1 2] with source 
           % alphabet [-2 -1 0 1 2]
F5Za       % Decompress with target alphabet [0 1 2 3 4]
2-         % Subtract 2 to transform alphabet into [-2 -1 0 1 2]
i)         % Input N and use as (modular, 1-based) index into the sequence
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 40 bytes

Just creates a lookup table and accesses it cyclically, as in ETHproductions's answer. Unnamed function, 1-indexed.

```
Join[s={2,1,1,2,-1,1},-s][[#~Mod~12+1]]&
```

Answer (score 3):

## WinDbg, 26 bytes

```
?(85824331b>>@$t0%c*3&7)-2
```

Input is passed in through the pseudo-register `$t0`. 0-indexed. +2 of each term in the sequence is stored in 3 bits making `85824331b`.

How it works:

```
? (85824331b >> @$t0 % c * 3 & 7) - 2 ;*? Evalutes the expression. Shifts 85824331b to get
                                       *the 3 bits for the @$t0'th term (mod c (12) when
                                       *the sequence repeats). Bitwise AND by 7 to get the
                                       *desired 3 bits, finally subtract 2 since the terms
                                       *where stored as +2.
```

Sample output, a loop printing the first 14 values of the sequence:

```
0:000> .for(r$t0=0;@$t0<e;r$t0=@$t0+1){?(85824331b>>@$t0%c*3&7)-2}
Evaluate expression: 1 = 00000001
Evaluate expression: 1 = 00000001
Evaluate expression: 2 = 00000002
Evaluate expression: -1 = ffffffff
Evaluate expression: 1 = 00000001
Evaluate expression: -2 = fffffffe
Evaluate expression: -1 = ffffffff
Evaluate expression: -1 = ffffffff
Evaluate expression: -2 = fffffffe
Evaluate expression: 1 = 00000001
Evaluate expression: -1 = ffffffff
Evaluate expression: 2 = 00000002
Evaluate expression: 1 = 00000001
Evaluate expression: 1 = 00000001
```

Answer (score 3):

## Java, 32 bytes

```
n->"334130110314".charAt(n%12)-50
```

Since this is Java, the answer is 0-indexed.

### Testing and ungolfed:

```
class Ideone {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
    java.util.function.IntFunction f = n->"334130110314".charAt(n%12)-50;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      System.out.printf("%d -> %d%n", i, f.apply(i));
    }
  }
}
```

[Test on Ideone](http://ideone.com/DrjtfE)

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, <s>45</s> <s>41</s> 38 bytes

Thanks to @MartinEnder for 3 bytes.

```
±0=±1=1;±n_:=±(n-2)+±(n-1)(1-2n~Mod~2)
```

0-indexed.

**Usage**

```
±5
```

> `-2`

Comment: You can probably save three bytes by defining a unary operator `±` instead of a function `a`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>39 35</s>  32 bytes

```perl6
{(1,1,{|(($/=$^a+$^b),$b-$/)}...*)[$_]}
```

```perl6
{(|(334130110314.comb X-2)xx*)[$_]}
```

```perl6
{(|334130110314.comb xx*)[$_]-2}
```

```perl6
{334130110314.substr($_%12,1)-2}
```

Answer (score 1):

## R, 38 bytes

Uses the lookup table solution inspired by @ETHproductions JS answer.

```
c(s<-c(2,1,1,2,-1,1),-s)[scan()%%12+1]
```

Edit: Forgot to mention that this is 1-indexed.

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 117 Bytes

Golfed:

```
int A(int n){var f=new List<int>{0,1,1};for(int i=3;i<=n;i++){f.Add(i%2>0?f[i-1]+f[i-2]:f[i-2]-f[i-1]);}return f[n];}
```

Ungolfed:

```
public int A(int n)
{
  var f = new List<int> { 0, 1, 1 };

  for (int i = 3; i <= n; i++)
  {
    f.Add(i % 2 > 0 ? f[i - 1] + f[i - 2] : f[i - 2] - f[i - 1]);
  }

  return f[n];
}
```

Testing:

```
var alternatingFibonacci = new AlternatingFibonacci();
Console.WriteLine(alternatingFibonacci.B(10));
1
```

Comment: Compile to a Func<int, int> so `public int A(int n)` is now `n=>`, you can remove the braces around the for statement saving 2 bytes,  you can pre increment the `i` in the loop i.e. `++i <= n` and set `i = 2` saving 3 bytes because it removes the `i++` at the end of the statement

Comment: Also see my answer if you kept track of the previous variables instead of creating a list of them all it is a lot shorter

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](http://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 22 bytes

```
34*@%"334130110314"E≈¬
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=MzQqQCUiMzM0MTMwMTEwMzE0IkXiiYjCrA&input=NTA)

Explanation:

```
34*@%"334130110314"E≈¬
34*@%                   input % 12
     "334130110314"E    get that character in the string
                    ≈¬  convert to int, subtract 2
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7, <s>88</s> <s>82</s> 79 bytes

golfed:

```
int f(int n){int c,i=0,a=1,b=1;for(;i<n;){c=i++%2>0?a-b:a+b;a=b;b=c;}return b;}
```

ungolfed:

```
int f(int n)
{
    int c, i = 0, a = 1, b = 1;
    for (; i < n;)
    {
        c = i++ % 2 > 0 ? a - b : a + b;
        a = b;
        b = c;
    }
    return b;
}
```

[Try it online](https://ideone.com/8MSHDc)

Comment: Since you go the "logical" way, here are some hints: 1. you forgot to declare `int` as return type. 2. you can spare bytes by moving the assignment of 0 to the declaration of i: `int c,i=0` and `for(;i<n;){`. 3. You can remove parenthesis around the ternary operator condition.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire thanks dude :) fixed. nice solution btw

Answer (score 1):

### DC, 55 bytes

```
?sd[ln1+snly[[+2Q]sEln2%1=E-]xlyrsylnld>r]sr1sy0sn1lrxp
```

0-indexed.

```
?sd                                                     takes input and stores
                                                        it in register d

                                            1sy0sn1     stores 1 in register y
                                                        and 0 in register n and
                                                        appends 1 to the stack

   [ln1+snly                                            adds 1 to register n and
                                                        appends the value of
                                                        register y to the stack

            [[+2Q]sEln2%1=E-]                           adds or subtracts the
                                                        the two values on the
                                                        stack depending on
                                                        parity of n

                             xlyrsylnld>r]              does the rest of the
                                                        stuff required to store
                                                        the new values properly
                                                        and quits if it has
                                                        done enough iterations

                                          sr            stores the main macro
                                                        in register r

                                                   lrxp executes the macro and
                                                        prints the stack
```

Register d stores the index of the value. Register n counts the number of iterations completed. Register r stores the main macro. Register y stores the later value in the sequence, while the stack contains the earlier value in the sequence.

Visual explanation of whats going on in the big loop (assuming addition):

```
register: y=1     y=1   y=1    y=1   y=1    y=2
stack:     1      1 1    2     2 1   1 2     1
               ly     +     ly     r     sy
```

The check to determine whether to add or subtract takes the counter modulo two and uses [this trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77698/tips-for-golfing-in-dc) to make an if then else construction.

At the end the stack contains a single number, the desired value, which is printed with `p`.

(I'm new to `dc`, so I'd expect there are some obvious improvements to be made here.)

Answer (score 0):

## [ForceLang](https://github.com/SuperJedi224/ForceLang), 153 bytes

```
def s set
s a 1
s b 1
s p 1
s k io.readnum()
if k=0
goto b
label a
s c b.mult p
s c a+c
s a b
s b c
s p p.mult -1
s k k+-1
if k
goto a
label b
io.write a
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Turtlèd](http://github.com/Destructible-Watermelon/Turtl-d), 35 bytes

```
#112-1_--_1-2#?:[*l+].(-r'1)(_"-2")
```

0 indexed

### Explanation:

```
#112-1_--_1-2#                      the 12 values of sequence. - is -1, _ is -2
              ?:                    input a number and move right that many
                [*l+]               move back to the asterisk on start cell, 
                                    increment sting pointer by amount moved
                     .              write pointed char
                      (-r'1)        if it was -, move right, write 1
                            (_"-2") if it was _, write "-2"
      [print grid]
```

#### [Try it online!](http://turtled.tryitonline.net/#code=IzExMi0xXy0tXzEtMiM_OlsqbCtdLigtcicxKShfIi0yIik&input=MA)

Answer (score 0):

## ABCR, 43 bytes

```
)AAB)ABB..A))A..A)AA(ABB.)A+A)))AiB5aAb(Bxo
```

Explanation: the first part (`)AAB)ABB..A))A..A)AA(ABB.)A+A)))A`) sets up queue A to contain [1, 1, 2, -1, 1, -2, -1, -1, -2, 1, -1, 2], keeping all other queues empty.  `iB` stores our desired term, and the loop `5aAb(Bx` cycles through the the queue that many times.  `o` prints the front of the queue as a number, which will then be our desired answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 49 bytes

```
@cmd/cset/a"n=%1%%12,~!(n%%3)*(1|-!(n%%5*(n/4)))"
```

Takes input as a command-line parameter. Explanation: Closed form uses the following observations:

- Sequence is cyclic with period 12
- Every third term is ±2 while other terms are ±1
- Terms after the third are negative except multiples of 5 (after reducing modulo 12)

We therefore start by reducing modulo 12 (to save 2 bytes). We then reduce modulo three and invert the result, which is 1 for multiples of 3 or 0 otherwise. We then bitwise not that value, giving us -2 for multiples of 3 or -1 otherwise. We then reduce modulo 5 and separately divide by 4, giving zero for terms 1, 2, 3, 5, 10 and 12 (0). Inverting and negating gives us -1 for those values and zero for other values. We then bitwise or that with 1 and multiply with the earlier calculation.

Answer (score 0):

## TI-Basic, 26 bytes

Unfortunately, very uninteresting approach. I could not find anything shorter. The list is 1-indexed.

```
Input :{1,1,2,-1,1,-2:augment(Ans,-Ans:Ans(X
```

Answer (score 0):

### C#, <s>73</s> 71 bytes

This uses 0-indexed values of n.

```
n=>{int a=1,b=1,i=0,r;for(;++i<n;){r=i%2>0?a+b:a-b;a=b;b=r;}return b;};
```

Formatted version:

```
Func<int, int> f = n =>
{
    int a = 1, b = 1, i = 0, r;

    for(; ++i < n;)
    {
        r = i % 2 > 0 ? a + b : a - b;
        a = b;
        b = r;
    }

    return b;
};
```