# Shortest Error Message

Tags: code-golf, error-message

**Challenge**

Write the shortest program that, when compiled or executed, produces a fatal error message smaller than the program itself. The error message may not be generated by the program itself, such as Python's `raise`. A valid answer must include both the code and the error message. Shortest valid answer wins.

No error message does not count as an error message.

**Example (Lua)**

Code (46 bytes):

```
[
--aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Error (45 bytes):

```
[string "[..."]:1: unexpected symbol near '['
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62987/discussion-on-question-by-user72528-shortest-error-message).

Comment: @Dennis I guess that's one way of solving the "OP doesn't edit clarifications into question" problem.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, which got the most votes; however, this was tagged [tag:code-golf], so you should accept [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/133886/61563), which is the shortest.

Comment: @smartpeople is this: "`__main__.CodeException: Raised an &rror.`"  my error or is this:"`Raised an &rror.`"

Comment: TrumpScript running in China?

Comment: Is an input allowed (adding the used input to the byte-count of course)? I could save a couple bytes by taking a one-char input and trying to parse it as a number.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

## [ed](https://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed-msg.html), 3 bytes

*Note: Most of the answers here are ignoring the trailing newline printed as part of the error message in their count.  But I don’t see anything in the question to justify ignoring it, and the author [commented that the newline should be included](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/133840/shortest-error-message?answertab=votes#comment328883_133840).  So unless the question is changed, I’m going to include it.*

Code (with trailing newline):

```
??
```

Error (with trailing newline):

```
?
```

Comment: Actually, this is impossible to beat. :P

Comment: Not entirely, if for some reason the newline alone counts as an error, or if there exists an error that is one character long and does not have a trailing new line, then it's possible.

Comment: Can ed do addition and primality testing? Or is that not required for this type of challenge?

Comment: @StepHen Yes, it can do addition and primality testing in unary via the usual regex-with-backreferences trick.

Comment: well, you got my upvote :D

Comment: This answer was exactly my first thought on reading the question.  Ed is justly famed for its succinct error messages.

Comment: Very clever, but '?' isn't fatal.

Comment: If the error isn't fatal as Mark points out, I'm afraid this answer is invalid. Please edit the answer if there's an ed implementation where the error actually terminates the program, and flag it for moderator attention so that it can be undeleted.

Comment: As pointed out in a flag, the error is fatal if the code isn't read from a terminal. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S035/z@Ry8nVzT/IlUuPq5zL3p4rkcvRLcQ1CMz9/x8A "ed – Try It Online")

Comment: This outputs `0\n?\n` to STDERR, which is longer than the source code. This can be fixed at no cost, however, by using `-s`.

Comment: @Makonede The `0\n` only appears when providing a 0-byte input file as an argument to `ed`. The TIO [wrapper](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/blob/master/wrappers/ed) does this, but one doesn’t need to do so in general. If one does, the `0\n` is not part of an error message: it appears before any code is read, and indicates the size of the input file.

Answer (score 58):

## C (modern Linux), 19 bytes

Would've done my famous segfault but totallyhuman stole it.

```
main(){longjmp(0);}
```

Output (18 bytes):

```
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: You currently have a higher score than me so... Win-win?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62615/discussion-between-dennis-and-md-xf).

Comment: Are there no other locale with a shorter version (So that you could then use `main(){main();}`)?

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Not that I know of. Also, `main(){main();}` is not guaranteed to seg-fault.

Comment: @MDXF There is no guarantee (and with optimization enabled in gcc or clang, it end up in a endless loop or ignore the call). But on Code Golf we need a working implementation not a guarantee.

Comment: How about `main(){free(1);}`? On my device, it aborts.

Answer (score 57):

## Python 2, 35 bytes

```py
import sys;sys.tracebacklimit=000;a
```

Gives error:

```
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Comment: modifying the traceback limit... nice one

Comment: This is clever!

Answer (score 36):

### JavaScript (Firefox), 31 bytes

```
# This is a comment, right? ...
```

Throws this error:

```
SyntaxError: illegal character
```

Tested in the console of Firefox 54.0.1 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 28):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>87</s> 79 bytes

*-8 bytes thanks to Zacharý and Erik the Outgolfer.*

```python
from __future__ import braces
#i am most surely seriously actually totallyhuman
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FclLCsAgDADRfU8R6A16oZCKomCM5LPw9Nau5sHM5VXGs3dRYUAs4aEZERpPUYdXKWW77gbEwGIOdn5fYFmbhB1R8qB@4OJ/azCNvT8)

### Error message, 78 bytes:

Assuming the code is stored in a file named `a`.

```python
  File "a", line 1
    from __future__ import braces
SyntaxError: not a chance
```

This is actually a nice little Easter egg in Python. :D

Comment: You can assume a one-char file name!

Comment: Assuming a 1-char file name, you can golf to [this](https://tio.run/##HclLCoAwDADRvacIeLAQQ0sLjZF8Fp4@FlfzYHiQsdKq6qYCiD0jrSHClEct4DLi5sc5gQREPcD3Xy94s6npW8SRtDZC4@9IobvqAw).

Comment: Heh, nice. - - -

Comment: But the error message has to be smaller than the program itself...

Comment: @LeakyNun Fixed.

Comment: If you use IDLE you can get `\s\sFile "<stdin>", line 1\nSyntaxError: not a chance` which is only 50 bytes [`\s` is a space and `\n` is a newline], so you can get a 51 byte program..

Answer (score 25):

## Haskell, 13 bytes

```
main = (main)
```

Save as `t.hs` or another one-character name, compile with `ghc`, and run.  Error message (with trailing newline):

```
t: <<loop>>
```

Answer (score 20):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 26 bytes

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/3w4XsPr/HwA)

Every error message in Fish is `something smells fishy...`, so this just moves the pointer right enough times to be longer than that and attempts to duplicate the top of the stack, which is empty at the time.

Comment: I like it, and it's definately the most fishy of all solutions :-)

Comment: @Xan-KunClark-Davis *sigh* you had to... :P

Answer (score 20):

## [Taxi](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Taxi/), <s>38</s> 21 bytes

```
Switch to plan "abc".
```

Produces:

```
error: no such label
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0msyPz/P7g8syQ5Q6EkX6EgJzFPQSkxKVlJ7/9/AA)

*-17 bytes thanks to Engineer Toast*

Tries to switch to "abc", which does not exist. You would have `[abc]` somewhere.

Comment: You can get down to 21 bytes with `Switch to plan "abc".` producing `error: no such label`. This might be one of the few [tag:code-golf] challenges where Taxi beats some traditional languages.

Comment: @EngineerToast thanks, didn't think of that one.

Answer (score 20):

## System V shell, 25 bytes

```
mount /dev/hda1 /mnt/hda1
```

Error message (23 bytes):

```
mount: not a typewriter
```

"Not a typewriter" or `ENOTTY` is an error code defined in `errno.h` on Unix systems. This is used to indicate that an invalid ioctl (input/output control) number was specified in an ioctl system call. On my system, in `/usr/include/asm-generic/errno-base.h`, I can find this line:

```
#define ENOTTY          25      /* Not a typewriter */
```

In Version 6 UNIX and older, I/O was limited to serial-connected terminal devices, such as a teletype (TTY). These were usually managed through the `gtty` and `stty` system calls. If one were to try to use either of these system calls on a non-terminal device, `ENOTTY` was generated.

Nowadays, there is naturally no need to use a teletype. When `gtty` and `stty` were replaced with `ioctl`, `ENOTTY` was kept. Some systems still display this message; but most say "inappropriate ioctl for device" instead.

Comment: Please explain...

Comment: @MegaMan Updated with explanation.

Comment: Upvote for actually enlightening explanation.

Answer (score 20):

### JavaScript (Firefox), 21 bytes

```
(a=null)=>a.charAt(1)
```

**Error (20 bytes)**: `TypeError: a is null`

Comment: D'oh! I knew there was a shorter one...

Comment: I had the same idea, came up with a=null;a.x01234567890

Same amount of bytes

Answer (score 14):

## [TrumpScript](https://github.com/samshadwell/TrumpScript), 30 bytes

```
We love NATO!
America is great
```

Error message:

```
Trump doesn't want to hear it
```

Comment: P.S. Error codes are in [constants.py](https://github.com/samshadwell/TrumpScript/blob/master/src/trumpscript/constants.py)

Answer (score 12):

## **Javascript (V8), 24 bytes**

```
decodeURIComponent('%');
```

Error, 23 bytes:

```
URIError: URI malformed
```

Tested on *Nodejs v6.11.0* and *Google Chrome v59.0.3071.115*.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/JTUZSIcGeTrn5xbk56XmlWioq6prWv//DwA)

Note that TIO expands the error message.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 11):

## QBasic, 11 bytes

There are two solutions of 11 bytes in QBasic, one of which might be golfed further. The shortest error message QBasic has is `overflow`, and can be triggered as such:

```
i%=i%+32677
```

This throws `overflow` because the max for an integer (`i%`) is `32676`. I couldn't get the `32677` golfed without QBasic auto-casting this to long...

Another error, at 11 bytes, would be `out of data`. QBasic has `DATA` statements that store data in the program, which can later be accessed by `READ` statements. Issuing more `READ`s than `DATA`s causes the error:

```
READ a$ '--
```

Note that the statement is padded with a comment to get it up to the length of the error message. Yes, I have an error message with a shorter program, and a program with a shorter error message ...

Answer (score 11):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 309 bytes

```
In this answer, I coded it so that the program errors when executed․
Also, according to code-golf statistics, only a small percentage of people who view my answers actually upvote․ 
So if you enjoy this answer, please consider upvoting - it's free, and you can change your mind at any time․ 
Enjoy the answer․
```

I request that you imagine [Epic Dawn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=beCC9xJjLZQ) by Bobby Cole is playing while reading this answer.

### The Error

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\61419\Desktop\Vyxal\Vyxal.py", line 867, in <module>
    exec(line)
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\61419\Desktop\Vyxal\Vyxal.py", line 592, in VY_int
    return int(item, base)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

## Explained

This fails immediately on the first instruction it sees: `I`. It tries to convert the empty input to base 10 (which is impossible)

Comment: PPCG: YouTube edition. 

Comment: [-308 bytes](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%29&inputs=&header=&footer=) (2.4.1 online only)

Answer (score 10):

## C (Modern Linux), 19 bytes

I suggested this in chat, but nobody took the oppurtunity. :P Credit to [MD XF's hilarious answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/121264/).

```c
main(){puts('s');;}
```

### Error message, 18 bytes

```
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: But the error message has to be smaller than the program itself...

Comment: Byte counts were screwed up, my bad.

Comment: This is a generic message printed by the shell when subprocess terminates with exit code 139. The C program itself produces no error message at all.

Comment: @totallyhuman DV was mine, forgot to reverse it after we cleared up the issue.

Comment: @Dennis Exit code 139 is actually another lie made up by the shell. Unix distinguishes between signal 11 (`W_EXITCODE(0, 11) == 11`) and exit code 139 (`W_EXITCODE(139, 9) == 139 << 8`). Shells set `$?` non-surjectively to `WIFEXITED(wstatus) ? WEXITSTATUS(wstatus) : WTERMSIG(wstatus) + 128`, but most languages expose the difference.

Comment: @Anders Is `WIFEXITED(wstatus)` equivalent to `DIVORCE(alimony)` by any chance?

Answer (score 10):

### Commodore 64 Basic, 15 bytes

```
?SYNTAX   ERROR
```

Produces

```
?SYNTAX  ERROR
```

(Note two spaces in the error message, where the program has three)

`?SYNTAX  ERROR` is tied with `?VERIFY  ERROR` as the third-shortest error message that C64 Basic can produce, and the shortest that can be reliably triggered by code (the shortest message, `BREAK IN 1`, requires user interaction, while `?LOAD  ERROR` requires a defective tape or floppy disk, and `?VERIFY  ERROR` requires the presence of a floppy or tape containing a file that doesn't match the program in RAM).

Comment: Ha, didn't even see this when I posted [mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135118/61563). Always good to see another BASIC user... +1

Answer (score 9):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>215</s> 189 bytes

```powershell
[]
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X4lLPXH4AfX//wE)

So, PowerShell has ... verbose ... error messages. Additionally, most non-syntax error messages are Runtime Exceptions, meaning that they're non-fatal, which reduces this problem to needing to find a short parsing error.

<s>I *think* this is one of the shortest, if not *the* shortest,</s> @TessellatingHeckler has demonstrated this is the shortest parsing error, and it still weighs in at `188` bytes just for the error message. So we basically need to append enough `1`s to reach `189` bytes of "code."

Running this locally on `c:\a.ps1` for example, will cut down on the byte count by a handful as it's just a shorter file path, but then it's not available on TIO.

Produces error:

```powershell
At /tmp/home/.code.tio.ps1:1 char:2
+ []
+  ~
Missing type name after '['.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingTypename
```

Comment: I was asked three questions in the comments, one of which you asked, but the two you didn't ask both applied to your answer, and not yours.

Comment: @user72528 Yeah, I found that amusing as well.

Comment: You can use a one char file name!

Comment: @Zacharý I can, but then it's not reproducible on TIO due to how TIO handles the sandboxing. I prefer to keep it usable on TIO than to save a few bytes.

Comment: That's fine (the `!` wasn't needed), since this definitely won't be winning anything.

Comment: What about `[]` which looks like a shorter error `Missing type name after '['` and depending on exactly how you count could be around 190 - https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/PzqWy3Dogv//AQ (taken from the [parser strings here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/System.Management.Automation/resources/ParserStrings.resx) that looks like the shortest parser error to me  `([xml](gc .\ParserStrings.resx)).root.data.value | sort { $_.length } -Desc`).

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Nice job polling the code to find a shorter error message. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>29</s> 28 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to JarkoDubbeldam*

```r
a #abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy
```

Throws the error `Error: object 'a' not found`which is 27 bytes.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P1FBOTEpOSU1LT0jMys7Jzcvv6CwqLiktKy8ovL/fwA)

Comment: `a #abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy`'s error `Error: object 'a' not found` is one byte shorter.

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam thank you.

Answer (score 7):

## Ruby (<s>33</s> 32 bytes)

**32 bytes**

```
&
#abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz12
```

Throws the error (assuming in a file named "a"):

**31 bytes**

```
a:1: syntax error, unexpected &
```

**Edit**: Shaved a byte off by using `&` instead of `<<` thanks to [Eric](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/65905/eric-duminil), who also came up with an even shorter Ruby solution:
http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135087/65905

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: @EricDuminil nice! I thought all the single character operators were quoted in the error message, but you're right: `&` isn't. Neat! Also, good find with the hex escape. I was struggling to find a shorter and non-stack-trace fatal error message other than a syntax error.

Comment: @ameketa: I actually wrote a bruteforce program and tested every possible 1, 2 and 3-byte Ruby program :D Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 5):

## Brainf**k, 17 bytes, [this interpreter](http://fatiherikli.github.io/brainfuck-visualizer/#KysrKysrKysrKysrKysrPDw=)

```
+++++++++++++++<<
```

Brainf**k is such a simple language that almost every interpreter has a different error message. This one uses `Memory Error: -1` for when the pointer is moved to the left too much and you attempt another operation

Comment: I guess choosing an interpreter is as much a part of the challenge as choosing a language.

Comment: @user72528 Well here, we define a language by its interpreter, so this challenge is a bit about choosing the interpreter with the shortest error messages :)

Comment: Who beats brainfuck? Nobody? Alright.

Comment: The unbeatable solution would a two byte solution which causes an error of 1 character.

Comment: @Zacharý Certainly lol

Comment: weird interpreter; wraps calls value but not cells layout

Comment: @Uriel It is quite weird. Of course, I'm abusing that just because it exists :)

Comment: The reasonable thing for brainfuck is to support an infinite number of cells of infinite value on both sides.

Answer (score 5):

## [Common Lisp](http://www.clisp.org/), 20 bytes

```lisp
(/ 1 0))))))))))))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JLC74/19DX8FQwUATBfz/DwA)

**Error Message**

```lisp
/: division by zero
```

Comment: o_o unbalanced parentheses in Lisp ... you learn something new every day.

Comment: If you replace the 0 with 1, it will error on the parens but it doesn't get that far with 0. I just needed to add characters to be longer than the message

Answer (score 5):

## TryAPL, 11 bytes

Code (11):

```
'abcdefghij
```

Error (10):

```
open quote
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 11 bytes

Since I'm not clear on whether my [other answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/134957/18653) obeys the challenge rules, here's another alternative.

```perl
#line 0
die
```

Error output:

```perl
Died.
```

With an ending newline, for 6 bytes.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/185JzMvVcGAKyUz9f9/AA)

For some reason the Perl interpreter internal function `Perl_mess_sv` contains:

```perl
if (CopLINE(cop))
    Perl_sv_catpvf(aTHX_ sv, " at %s line %" IVdf,
                    OutCopFILE(cop), (IV)CopLINE(cop));
```

where `CopLINE(cop)` gets the current code context's line number.  So if that line number happens to evaluate to zero, Perl skips adding the usual `" at <filename> line <n>"` to the error message.

Comment: It seems nor valid to me. IIRC `die` is for the program to exit.

Comment: How is that any different than python `raise`?

Comment: Well, the OP might have been referring to either generating the *error* or the *error message*. I commented on which one he meant.

Answer (score 5):

## ZX Spectrum Basic, 9 bytes

```
RUN USR 8
```

produces:

[image: Error message]

Explanation:

I am (exceptionally) counting ASCII representation of the program for length purposes, including the end of line (it's not really important, since we could always pad a shorter program with spaces).

Usually, ZX Spectrum error messages are longer and more helpful than this - the ROM routine at 0x0008 expects error code following the machine code call to `RST 8`., and fetches some random (deterministic) byte from the ROM, which produces this nonsensical error message `M`. `5` is the error number, `,` is added by the error printing routine and `0:1` is the line:command position of the error.

Comment: Actually this is 9 bytes normally anyway, because the ZX Spectrum doesn't evaluate numbers at run time, so there are actually 6 hidden bytes which allow it to access the binary representation of 8 directly.

Answer (score 5):

## [ArnoldC](https://lhartikk.github.io/ArnoldC/), 150 bytes

```
IT'S SHOWTIME
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE b
YOU SET US UP 0
GET TO THE CHOPPER b
HERE IS MY INVITATION b
HE HAD TO SPLIT 0
ENOUGH TALK
YOU HAVE BEEN TERMINATED
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hcw7DsJAEAPQPqdwR8sVFmJlRmQ/2pkNSsmnRCBxf2kJ6Szr2bfv@/N6PnpXPxhM8tU1chCuOEtV8xgMXknchzU3GB3N0AqOw7Rlz3DhZnMprBsSVkINcYWmRT245rT3kDD@vZVZfZsz5TYJPMyX/VrCQpzIBGeNmoJz7P0H)

Error is 94 bytes (including trailing newline):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at code.main(Hello.java)
```

---

Preserved because I think this is more funny - spoiler: it was those dang teenage pranksters.

## [ArnoldC](https://lhartikk.github.io/ArnoldC/), 280 bytes

```
IT'S SHOWTIME
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE BRBDoorBetterNotBeThosePeskyTeenagePranksters
YOU SET US UP 0
GET YOUR ASS TO MARS BRBDoorBetterNotBeThosePeskyTeenagePranksters
DO IT NOW
I WANT TO ASK YOU A BUNCH OF QUESTIONS AND I WANT TO HAVE THEM ANSWERED IMMEDIATELY
YOU HAVE BEEN TERMINATED
```

Pseudocode:

```
start program
new variable
set to 0
set new variable to output from function
call function
take input
end program
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY4xbsMwEAR7vWK7tPkCaZ5DIiEp844RVAoJYQM2REBSk9fLtBvX6RY7i8FOy1xvvz/77uSNwTYO4jx1lkYcbHIsXjEkEUEnbWpddNm2soS66SKXupa@rNc/KWWezqVfpvm6Nrx2Y8xgEmRG7vHefbTcugTFzRfhVeJ/Kk2EE4Q4dA6DCvLQKP58aKGgczhYxCNOmVhcDAwVDF5Tq74JYsm3ngdK1KD3ZJwS@hqfh58TTRQglLwLjZh9vwM)

Generates a "no input" error. (Almost all other errors in ArnoldC include a large piece of boilerplate):

279 bytes (including trailing newline):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at code.main(Hello.java)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 5 bytes

```perl
die$/
```

Outputs a newline, for one byte.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z8lM1VF//9/AA)

Comment: ._. Now ... if only perl errors on the empty file!

Comment: Wait, is this a violation of the "may not be generated by the program itself"? I didn't understand what that rule was saying.

Comment: @Zacharý ... giving an error message with total length negative one?

Comment: This might be invalid ... or not, depends on whether the OP meant the **error** or the **error message**

Comment: ^ clarification: whether a program errors directly or creates an error message directly

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript (Firefox), <s>29</s> 27 bytes

```
new Date('-').toISOString()
```

throws `RangeError: invalid date` which is 24 bytes.
Tested on Firefox 54.0.1 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 4):

## GW-Basic, 9 bytes

Enter:

```
?&H100000
```

This will yield the following error message:

```
Overflow
```

I believe this is the shortest error message in GW-Basic. The reason I used a hexadecimal constant is that while GW-Basic doesn't support long integers, it does support single and double(!) precision floating point numbers.

Answer (score 4):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php) (on [TIO](https://tio.run/#)), 34 bytes

```
 
Nope, it's not valid Whitespace!
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X4HLL78gVUchs0S9WCEvv0ShLDEnM0UhHK5E8f9/AA)

All characters that aren't a space, tab, or newline are ignore in Whitespace. So this program is actually `SNSSS` (where `S` is space, and `N` is newline). The first three (`SNS`) is the command to duplicate the value at the top of the stack. Since the stack is still empty, it gives the error:

```
wspace: user error (Can't do Dup)
```

I tried other errors, but this seems to be the shortest. Most errors where it tries to use a value on the stack which isn't present are similar, but longer. Here is a list of all possible errors (I could find) on TIO (for the first one it requires a character input, which it tries to read and print as number, so I've excluded that one - [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##TYo7CoAwEAXreIocwUPY2IRg0oksqy4Y0BDy0eOvBi3kVW9mrs1lSgEXYh6NrFMN6JI2aKexHiOhK2F3C2aqzArVWGEFDIQrGNv1CjCBL8dMsepP5ujopLc38kE6Op9/KTPe)):

```
wspace: Prelude.read: no parse
wspace: user error (Can't do Dup)
wspace: user error (Can't do Swap)
wspace: Prelude.!!: index too large
wspace: user error (Can't do Store)
wspace: user error (Can't do Return)
wspace: user error (Can't do Discard)
wspace: user error (Can't do Slide 0)
wspace: user error (Can't do ReadNum)
wspace: user error (Can't do Retrieve)
wspace: user error (Can't do ReadChar)
wspace: <stdin>: hGetChar: end of file
wspace: <stdin>: hGetLine: end of file
wspace: user error (Can't do OutputNum)
wspace: Prelude.chr: bad argument: (-1)
wspace: user error (Can't do Infix Plus)
wspace: user error (Can't do OutputChar)
wspace: user error (Undefined label ( ))
wspace: user error (Can't do Infix Minus)
wspace: user error (Can't do Infix Times)
wspace: user error (Can't do If Zero " ")
wspace: user error (Can't do Infix Divide)
wspace: user error (Can't do Infix Modulo)
wspace: user error (Can't do If Negative " ")
wspace: Input.hs:(108,5)-(109,51): Non-exhaustive patterns in function parseNum'
wspace: Unrecognised input\nCallStack (from HasCallStack):\n  error, called at Input.hs:103:11 in main:Input
wspace: Stack space overflow: current size 33624 bytes.\nwspace: Relink with -rtsopts and use `+RTS -Ksize -RTS' to increase it.
```

---

NOTE: Whitespace compilers have their own implementations for error messages. All these errors above are on TIO. If I use the online Whitespace compiler [vii5ard](http://vii5ard.github.io/whitespace/) instead, and use the same program at the top, it will give this error instead:

```
ERROR: Runtime Error: Stack underflow
```

So using the vii5ard online Whitespace compiler I could lower my byte-score to:

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php) (on [vii5ard](http://vii5ard.github.io/whitespace/)), 15 bytes

```
Unexpected EOF!
```

Which is the 'program' `S` (a single space), resulting in the error:

```
Unexpected EOF
```

(Which would result in [`wspace: Unrecognised input\nCallStack (from HasCallStack):\n  error, called at Input.hs:103:11 in main:Input` on TIO](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/PzQvtaIgNbkkNUXB1d9N8f9/AA)).

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>410</s> 411 bytes

```
One plus one is two, two plus two is four.
And now, some random character spam just because I can.
3...
2...
1...
GO!

ooi1u4`o1i2)I#1n[09i43u`1@#~!@#{10239`]ι@(~!)2ioausioe7u12o3iu71p3123`71i2`8127l5ruy;3948'p3298rv9pe8huep'r8i19o`8u'3pie8uiouI!^23uT7T17I3YJH~:L'I`YU2O123;121@

That should be about it, it errored. Guess that's what happens when you spam. Bye for now!


upvote if you liked my creativity


:)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JZDBSsNAEIbveYopPcRCCe5uJYleqheNCL3Ug4iSbTKS1Taz7O60BKHv5Uv4SnVTD/MzM/zzw3zk9cbg6bTqEeyWPVBsjIdwoPko/8uxicsPYpclt30LPR3m4GmH4HTf0g6aTjvdBHTgrd7BJ/sAG2w0e4QKGt1nicqyLJGjiFHuV5MkITKCFzUJI2fVVPSvl6VZKK7FcnqcLKff4lKqsn77/VleHCczaSgGGsKchSRlOBdWCanqPN7XhZD59srxcKPKRZFaJcvC7UuLRcdoU1cYUVJdcKqswYINcTV5l4rX@VrklXp5fDheP6VV/fIsVzH0RkixTJJ1pwP4jnjbxodAb4gDmDCPBegcOWwzuGf0kVK0ph4O40WnrcV@HLCHgfiMJYO7ASNFN/KL3yds9xQi74@zZWu@sIXdAI1DHczehCF6rmen0x8)

```
One plus one i...]ι...  # trimmed program
One plus one            # push empty string ("") twice
             i          # if top of stack is truthy...
              ...       # execute (trimmed) code (this is unreachable)
                 ]      # exit all opened statements
                  ι     # not exactly sure what this function does, but part of it forcefully converts top of stack to an integer (without error handling), therefore erroring
                   ...  # unreachable code as program has quit from the fatal error
```

## Error, 410 bytes

```
** (RuntimeError) Could not convert  to integer.
    (osabie) lib/interp/functions.ex:101: Interp.Functions.to_integer!/1
    (osabie) lib/interp/commands/special_interp.ex:113: Interp.SpecialInterp.interp_step/3
    (osabie) lib/interp/interpreter.ex:127: Interp.Interpretr.interp/3
    (osabie) lib/osabie.ex:62: Osabie.CLI.main/1
    (elixir) lib/kernel/cli.ex:105: anonymous fn/3 in Kernel.CLI.exec_fun/2
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Aubergine](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Aubergine), 53 bytes

```
0/0 Lots of wasted space. I don't know how Aubergine.
```

Outputs `SyntaxError: Invalid instruction (0) at character 0.`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxNSi1Kz8xL/f/fQN9AwSe/pFghP02hPLG4JDVFobggMTlVT8FTISU/T71EITsvv1whA4gdYbr0/v8HAA)

Answer (score 3):

## TI-Basic, 9 bytes

Shortest error messages are 8 bytes each: `ERR:DATE`, `ERR:MODE`, `ERR:STAT`, and `ERR:ZOOM`. I didn't consider `ERR:DATE` because that doesn't work on models without an internal clock. Also, I didn't go for `ERR:ZOOM` because it seemed too hard to trigger.

Program (9 bytes):

```
Seq:DrawInv X:::::
```

Error message: `ERR:MODE` (8 bytes)

Program (9 bytes):

```
median({1},{0::
```

Error message: `ERR:STAT` (8 bytes)

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 25 bytes

That was a fun exercise, thanks! There's probably a way to get a shorter error message with a SegFault, but I couldn't find any.

```
/\x
# Invalid hexa regexp
```

Error message:

```
a:1: invalid hex escape
```

24 bytes, including a trailing newline.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/Xz@mgktZwTOvLDEnM0UhI7UiUaEoNT21ouD/fwA)

## Ruby, 26 bytes

Here's my previous answer:

```
08
# No 8 allowed in octal
```

Error message:

```
a:1: Invalid octal digit
```

25 bytes, including a trailing newline.

Comment: I think you should separate your answers.

Comment: @SolomonUcko: Any reason why? There are many answers already. I just wanted to leave a trail of my previous answer. People usually just edit the byte count with <s>26</s> 25, but it's often for minor changes.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure why I said that, so nevermind.

Answer (score 3):

## GW-BASIC, 13 bytes

```
-------------
```

Error (12 bytes):

```
Syntax error
```

As GW-BASIC treats anything it doesn't recognize as a syntax error, there are a near-infinite amount of strings of length 13 that I could've used instead of `-------------`

Answer (score 3):

## Bash, 29 bytes

```
true&&false||false||a
```

error message:

```
a: command not found
```

it's really just filler of bash builtins before using an undefined command. This was the shortest bash error message I could think of.

Answer (score 3):

## TRS-80 Model 100 Basic, 10 bytes

Enter this:

```
??????????
```

Resulting error message:

```
?SN Error
```

All Basic error codes on this charming little machine are retrieved by using the error code to index into an array in ROM that looks like `NFSNRG`... and so on, so all error codes must be exactly 2 characters. With the 7 extra characters taken into account, all error messages will always be 9 bytes and hence 10 bytes is the shortest possible on this machine.

This is just one way to do it; there are countless more. It generates error `2`, code `SN`, which means syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

## C++ (on macOS High Sierra beta), 23 characters

```
int main(){*(int*)0=0;}
```

## Output: (22 characters)

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I do not recall whether previous versions of macOS provide the more traditional `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` response but adding spaces to the code to pad that out is pretty trivial.

Answer (score 3):

## LibreOffice Calc, 7 bytes

```
=aaaaaa
```

Result:

```
#NAME?
```

Answer (score 3):

## R, 9 bytes

[edited, because I can't count to 8]

code (9 bytes):

```
stop();;;
```

output (8 bytes, including trailing space and newline):

```
Error:
```

According to the manual, "`stop` stops execution of the current expression and executes an error action."  The first argument is meant to be an error message, but can be omitted.

Answer (score 3):

## BASIC (BBC micro)  9 bytes

```
>REN 9,-5
Silly.
```

Answer (score 3):

## dc (GNU 1.2) on Windows 10 x64, 185 bytes

`dc` doesn't crash fatally very often, and I couldn't be bothered to remember code that causes a segfault. I did recall some weird behavior involving [arrays](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83529/54071) that causes a sad and total loss of the current session.

```
zzz zzzzzzz zz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzzzzzzz

zzzz zzzzzzzzzzz zzz zzzzzzzzz zzz zzzzzzz zz zzzzzzzzz zz zz zz zzzzzzz zzzz
zzzzzz zzzzzzz zzz zzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzz zzzz zzz zzzz zzzzzzzz:zlz
```

Pushes numbers on the stack until the last five characters. `:z` stores the second-to-topmost number in the topmost-indexed slot in the array named `z`. Typically, this array would be linked through time and space to the current instance in the register named `z`. However, we haven't actually put anything there. Next, we try to `lz`, or copy the value on top of `z` to the top of the main stack. We can't: there's nothing there. I'm not sure why this mechanism triggers the failure that it does, but it works. (Or...doesn't.) The trailing newline is significant for two reasons: it puts the code in the black at 185, and pasting it into `dc` causes it to crash immediately.

Basically, we're running across a canyon, and as long as we don't look down, we're good. But once we look and realize we're floating in mid-air, we fall and crash hard, and little stars zoom around our poor befuddled heads.

### Error, 184 bytes

```
dc: garbage in value being duplicated

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

I'm not sure if only part of that is the actual error or what, so feel free to correct me. The code is obviously very flexible when it comes to length.

Comment: I was messing with this yesterday, and looking through the source for the shortest errors. I guess it's _possible_ that Win10 GNU dc actually has that massive error, but if it's anything like the dcs I've crashed in the same way the past couple of days and like the source I was cruising, that last bit is in fact your shell. zsh on Darwin just gives me a 'zsh: abort dc'; zsh on cygwin gave me some core dump error there. So yeah, I think you can golf it down a bit (but I do believe that error is the shortest/only(?) fatal error).

Answer (score 3):

#### Sinclair ZX81 - <strike>8 bytes</strike> <strike>4 bytes</strike> 2 bytes (2 BASIC tokens) using direct mode:

Newest solution

```
 PRINT A
```

Less old solution

```
 PRINT A+A
```

Old solution (8 bytes of memory):

```
 1 PRINT A
```

When you enter the command `RUN`, the following error is reported:

```
2/1
```

as in the screen shot below - Error code 2 means "Undefined variable" or something similar.

[image: ZX81 Undefined Variable error]

Answer (score 3):

## [Shakespeare Programming Language](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spl), 48 bytes

```
,a.Ajax,a.Act I:a.Scene I:a.[Enter Ajax]I error!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7I@f9fJ1HPMSuxAkQllyh4WiXqBSen5qWCWdGueSWpRQog@VhPhdSiovwixf//AQ)

Produces:

```
Unrecognized error encountered. No code output.
```

There's not much we can do about creating runtime errors, because the minimum overhead to create a program with two characters is 56 bytes, and you can't do much with one character. Instead, we settle for confusing the compiler, which means finding a sentence structure which doesn't fit the grammar rules. In this case, anything that isn't a character name after a character enters the stage.

Shorter error messages exist, for example `Error at line 1: act expected`, but the code compiled isn't valid, so you get an [extra few lines of gibberish](https://tio.run/##Ky7I@f9fJ1HPMSuxAkQllyh4WiXq/f8PAA) after the first error message.

Answer (score 3):

## IE9 Chinese version, 9 bytes

```
'12345'()
```

Outputs (assuming GBK encoding)

```
缺少函数
```

Answer (score 3):

## [/bin/sh ("dash" on Ubuntu Bionic)](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+package/dash), 20 bytes

```
cd /;ok="okokokok";@
```

Output is:

```
sh: 1: @: not found
```

The `cd /` command it just to make sure to switch to a location where there isn't a file named `@` since that's effectively what causes the error.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vim](https://www.vim.org), 17 bytes

```
            :w {
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/XwEJWJUrVHP9/w8A)

When you write to a file and you have an unmatched starting curly brace in the filename, it will give the error `E220: Missing }.` The code to get this error is very short, so we just pad it out with spaces to get to the length we want. You can't see this error on TIO, but it works in the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, 29 Bytes

```python
from __future__ import braces
```

### Error

```python
SyntaxError: not a chance
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 46 bytes

```
))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X5Mk8P8/AA)

This prints

```
Error at character 0: Unopened ')' character.
```

because in Brain-flak, all brackets must be balanced for the program to be valid.

Comment: [Same byte count different approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/133878/56656)

Answer (score 2):

## J, 10 bytes

```
0000000^.0
```

NaN error <--------  length 9

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 32 bytes

```
????????????????????????????????
```

#### Error message (31 bytes):

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?`

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=Pz8/Pz8/Pz8/Pz8/Pz8/Pz8/Pz8/Pz8/Pz8/Pz8/Pz8=&input=CgoKCgo=)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), 22 bytes

Dusting off the golfing cobwebs after a week's holidays; there's probably a shorter solution.

```
888888888888888888888z
```

Error:

```
No such function: N.z
```

[Test it](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=ODg4ODg4ODg4ODg4ODg4ODg4ODg4eg==&input=)

Comment: Another reminder that I probably shouldn't still be using `alert` for errors :P

Comment: @ETHproductions: if it wasn't for the intrusive `alert`, I probably wouldn't have remembered that error existed!

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 56 bytes

```php
<?php aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

produces

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file
```

Comment: Actually, the code would have to be two bytes longer: the error message must be _shorter_ than the code - and it includes a trailing newline. ;)

Comment: @Titus in fact, there was one `a` missing, since the Error msg has 55 bytes. Feel free to mess with DOS/Windows CRLF, I am using Linux. And no, the error msg does not include a newline, as it is usally followed by `in /path/to/file.php` or `in Command line code...`

Comment: point. Why do I remember a leading newline now? I´m confusing myself.

Answer (score 2):

## Batch <s>90</s> 18 bytes

```
@set/ab=1+*2*3*4*5
```

`Missing Operand`\
Golfed by SteveFest

Comment: This shold work: `@set/ab=1+2+345)` - `Missing Operand`

Comment: I was wrong: `@set/ab=1+*2*3*4*5` - `Missing Operator` It's just as few bytes. I'm sorry :(

Comment: @SteveFest that is fine XD

Answer (score 2):

## [Rexx (Regina)](http://www.rexx.org/), 25 bytes

```
interpret interpret 2+3+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0qtqPj/PzOvJLWooCi1RAHBMtI21jb8/x8A)

"interpret" treats the text following it as source and tries to execute it.
Since 2+3+1 is not included in quotes it treats it as a calculation and does that first.
Resulting in "interpret interpret 6"
The first "interpret" tells REXX to treat "interpret 6" as source.
So it executes it. This results in the attempt to execute 6 as source.

```
sh: 6: command not found
```

Answer (score 2):

## C#, 46 bytes

```c#
class P{public static int Main(string[]arg){}}
```

And produces the error at 45 bytes:

> 'P.Main()': not all code paths return a value

Probably a shorter way to do this in C# but I can't think of it.

Comment: You can remove the `public` and `string[]arg`. Also, leaving off a semicolon gives you this error instead: `error CS1002: ; expected`. In fact, you can remove the static, give it any type, and rename the function to anything you want to put your byte count above the error message length.

Comment: @TehPers that sounds like a sufficiently different approach that you could make it an answer.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 7, 43 bytes

Based on a [comment from the OP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/133840/shortest-error-message?page=3&tab=votes#comment328810_133840), we are allowed to assume the filename is 1 character long. This program has that assumption and my example uses the source code's filename z.java

```
// public static void main(String[] args){}
```

Error message:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class z
```

Answer (score 2):

### JAVA 8, 137 bytes error and 138 bytes code

```
package a;

public class a{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String f = "sdfgsfdgdffffffffffffffffffffffffsfdgfd";
        a = 5;
    }
}
```

produces the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    a cannot be resolved to a variable

    at a.a.main(a.java:6)
```

as this is my first time please tell me if i did something wrong

Answer (score 2):

## [Shakespeare Programming Language](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spl), 73 bytes

```
Errors.
Ajax, the web technology.
Act XLII:;.
Scene LXIX:;.
Ajax:You cat.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7I@f/ftagov6hYj8sxK7FCR6EkI1WhPDVJoSQ1OSMvPyc/vRIok1yiEOHj6WllrccVnJyal6rgE@EZAeKB9FhF5pcqJCeW6P3/DwA)

## Error message, 72 bytes

```
Runtime error at line 7: Ajax is not on stage, and thus cannot speak!
```

with one leading and two trailing newlines. Not sure whether the newlines count.

Comment: The `!` in the first line messes up the debug a bit

Comment: @JoKing Fixed, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

## [Eukleides](http://www.eukleides.org/), 17 bytes

Program:

```
a=centroid(empty)
```

Error:

```
X:1: empty set.
```

(Plus a newline). All fatal errors in Eukleides begin with `(filename):(line number):`  and end with a period and a newline. I combed the source, and found that `empty set` was the shortest error. At first, I thought I was out of luck, because I only saw the lengthy command `isobarycenter` throwing it, but spotted `centroid` throwing it as well. Then I couldn't figure out how to make an empty set; all my attempts got me a `syntax error` first. Turns out, `empty` is a constant for an empty set, something I never needed to know before. I am quite confident this is the shortest Eukleides solution.

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 28 bytes

```matlab
a=[];'Will cause error';a(1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/0TY61lo9PDMnRyE5sbQ4VSG1qCi/SN06UcNQ8/9/AA)

This throws this error:

```matlab
error: a(1): out of bound 0
```

**Damn, golfing error messages was cumbersome!** I have rewritten this answer 8 times now, since I've gradually found error messages that were one byte shorter than the previous one. I think this answer took me an hour, since I've made a complete rewrite 8 times... :(

---

Why is this the shortest error message?

- Relying on undefined functions or variables is not short enough (41)

  ```matlab
   error: 'a' undefined near line 1 column 1
  ```
- Relying on the wrong input type is not short enough (38)

  ```matlab
  error: mod: wrong type argument 'sq_string'
  error: whos: all arguments must be strings
  error: sum: wrong type argument 'cell'
  ```
- Relying on syntax errors is definitely not short enough (42)

  ```matlab
  parse error:

    syntax error

  >>> &
      ^
  ```
- Wrong indexing is not short enough (38)

  ```matlab
  error: scalar cannot be indexed with {
  ```
- Short function names and inputs that cause errors is not short enough (34)

  ```matlab
  error: a: No such file or directory
  error: load: unable to find file a
  ```

I've looked through **all** the functions in Octave, and I can't imagine anything being shorter than this.

Comment: In MATLAB this would give a 33 byte error message (`Index exceeds matrix dimensions.\n `). Still, beats mine by 9 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

### [@](https://esolangs.org/wiki/@), 29 bytes

```
Error: Unknown instruction E!
```

This tries to call the function E, which does not exist.

Output message:

```
Error: Unknown instruction E
```

Comment: I don't think the error is 'smaller than the program itself'

Comment: I switched the language. (Introducing the @ language)

Answer (score 2):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), <strike>61</strike> 57 bytes

```rust
fn main()->Result<(),usize>{[].binary_search(&0)?;Ok(())}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvn/Py1PITcxM09DU9cuKLW4NKfERkNTp7Q4syrVrjo6Vi8pMy@xqDK@ODWxKDlDQ81A097aP1tDQ1Oz9v9/AA)

Returns from the main function with `Error: 0`.

-3 bytes thanks to [Anders Kaesorg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/39242/anders-kaseorg)

Comment: I believe the goal is to make the error message shorter than the code.

Comment: @EasyasPi Fixed

Comment: `.ok_or(0)` seems like it breaks the rule that “the error message may not be generated by the program itself”. (But if not, [47 bytes](https://tio.run/##KyotLvn/Py1PITcxM09DU9cuKLW4NKfERkNTp9TCrrosNVkxOlavIL9AQ1MvPzs@v0jDQLP2/38A).)

Comment: @AndersKaseorg I think you're right, I found another 61-byte answer. Nice spot, though.

Comment: Your answer works on a slice too: [57 bytes](https://tio.run/##KyotLvn/Py1PITcxM09DU9cuKLW4NKfERkNTp7Q4syrVrjo6Vi8pMy@xqDK@ODWxKDlDQ81A097aP1tDQ1Oz9v9/AA)

Answer (score 2):

### Red, 29 Bytes

```
a/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1
```

```
Script Error: a has no value
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! I fixed the formatting, you can revert it if you preferred the original.

Answer (score 2):

## [Shakespeare Programming Language](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spl), 100 bytes

```
,.Ajax,.Puck,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Enter Ajax and Puck]Ajax:You cat!You is the quotient betweenyou zero.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYo5DoAwDAS/YnqUB9BRUNAhUSFEEcJKXHI4HHF8PuBqZzVzbmuMqclne6emCm752QmVmakdGAptwYKDNCHLA2nV6csaH8hZSXSnk2QE7cHLBBbqIRfAz69eHN7E@AE)

which produces

```
Runtime error at line 1: Unable to divide 1 by zero!
```

The error is 53 bytes including the trailing newline.

I really don't see how this can be improved (unless I missed something obvious). It loads 1 into Puck and attempts to divide him by 0.

Answer (score 2):

## [CPython 3.9](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/3.9), 71 bytes

```
__peg_parser__
########################################################
```

Not the shortest, but I found this "feature" worth sharing nonetheless: when Python 3.9 switched to a PEG parser, there was a special easter egg keyword `__peg_parser__` added which immediately causes a syntax error. The error outputted is:

```
  File "a", line 1
    __peg_parser__
    ^
SyntaxError: You found it!
```

This was removed in Python 3.10.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 67 bytes

``````python
`
  File ".code.tio", line 1
    ^`````
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
``````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P4FLQcEtMydVQUkvOT8lVa8kM19JRyEnMy9VwRAopaAQlwACXMGVeSWJFa5FRflFVgqZeWWJOZkpCsVgwf//AQ)

#### Error Message, 66 bytes

```python
  File ".code.tio", line 1
    `
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You can use a one char file name

Comment: Yeah, Thanks.... But to make it more TIO-interactive... if you know what I mean..

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 71 bytes

```python
a=b=c=d=e=f=g=h=i=j=k=l=m=n=o=p=q=r=s=t=u=v=w=x=y=z=A=B=C=D=E=F=1#
is=0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHJFcFQAADAuzY0wHOeQ2TpgyD7QjbR/Dcz7nM59JcQbu5yD08vhVKl1mh1eoPR28dktlhtvnY/katYIpU5Hw/V5BTCHw)

```python
  File ".code.tio", line 2
    is=0
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You can use a one char file name (TIO ... why)

Comment: @Zacharý /shrug not the shortest anyway, so I might as well make it consistent with TIO to avoid people asking me about the weird difference. I don't really care about bytecount lol

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 120 bytes

```
"Take it easy my brother JungHwan Min,Take it easy my brother LegionMammal978,Take it easy my brother Charlie"*666*666/0
```

> error-> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.

see comments for details...

Comment: Your program has to be longer; the exact error message is `Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.` (on Mathematica Kernel or Mathematica REPL 10.3 and before. The error is `Power: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.` on Mathematica REPL 11 and onwards)

Comment: And the above two error messages ignore the `FractionBox`; it's up to the OP to decide whether the `FractionBox` component has to be implemented.

Comment: I asked the question here: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/133840/shortest-error-message#comment330079_133840

Comment: @JungHwanMin Actually, there is an exact textual form for the error: [These exact bytes](https://git.io/v7kEo) are output to STDOUT when running this program as a script using version 10.1.0.0 of the kernel. The message is precisely 119 bytes long, as measured by `wc -c`; thus, this program would have to be at least 120 bytes long to satisfy the challenge requirements.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 Are you going to measure JungHwan's answer, too, (?) or this is just about my answer?

Comment: @Jenny_mathy Mostly about your answer, I didn't know that JungHuan answered.

Comment: yes, it is quite funny! posting all these things on the main chat and doing exactly the same!

Comment: @Jenny_mathy welp, I copy/pasted the error message from the Mathematica REPL. My error didn't really contain `FractionBox` or anything, which yours does. And yes, it is quite funny that you assumed I made the same mistake.

Comment: Edited version is very nice. 5/7 perfect score.

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 20 bytes

```bash
"" # waste of space!
```

Outputs `: command not found`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/X0lJQVmhPLG4JFUhP02huCAxOVXx/38A)

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 21 bytes

```bash
b # let's waste space
```

Outputs: `b: command not found`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P0lBWSEntUS9WKE8sbgkVaG4IDE59f9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 45 bytes

```lua
0/###########################################
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P/fQF@ZePD/PwA)

## Error message, 44 bytes

```lua
lua: .code.tio:1: unexpected symbol near '0'
```

Comment: You can use a one char file name!

Comment: I think its better that officialaimm didn't. Beat my example by 1. :P

Comment: How is it better that he didn't?

Comment: It's not a better result, I just found it more funny that he beat the example by exactly 1 byte.

Comment: That would be because I had forgotten the example was in Lua and I don't really know lua... :D

Answer (score 1):

## [Haystack](https://github.com/kade-robertson/haystack), 21 bytes

```
Wasted space is good!
```

Errors with `Where's the needle?`. Dosen't work on TIO.

Answer (score 1):

## C/*nix, 13 bytes

```
f(){free(f);}
```

On minimalist/old systems and shells that don't do fancy things, this prints:

```
Aborted
```

Of course, most modern shells print things like:

```
*** Error in `/tmp/file': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000400536 ***
Aborted
```

[TryItOnline](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NQ7M6rSg1VSNN07r2f25iZh5IQAPE@Q8A) prints a whole host of information.

Comment: Can you give an example of a system that only prints `Aborted`? (Without the specific checks that glibc uses to detect invalid the `free` and cleanly call `abort()`, the program would almost certainly just segfault.)

Comment: @AndersKaseorg I'm trying to remember on which system this didn't print extra information. I'm not at home so I don't have my ... extensive computer collection, when I get home I'll test it all around.

Comment: @MDXF found any?

Answer (score 1):

## [2Col](https://gunnerwolf.github.io/2col/), 50 bytes

```
Invalid code!
Line 0 contains invalid 2Col code!
1
```

[Try it on 2ColIDE](https://gunnerwolf.github.io/2col/?code=SW52YWxpZCBjb2RlIQpMaW5lIDAgY29udGFpbnMgaW52YWxpZCAyQ29sIGNvZGUhCjE)

Outputs:

```
Invalid code!
Line 0 contains invalid 2Col code!
```

With a trailing newline.

### Explanation

2Col only really has 1 error, and it's caused by the structure of the code being wrong. 2Col expects every line to be exactly 2 characters long, so if a line is longer or shorter than that, you get the above error.

Given that for this challenge the code must be longer than the error, the easiest way to achieve that is to use the error itself and add a byte.

Answer (score 1):

## Casio Basic, 10 bytes

```
{}=>a:a[1]
```

or, for **12 bytes**:

```
seq(x,x,1,0)
```

**Error for both (6 bytes):**

```
Domain
```

For the first one, accessing a list element outside the length of the list throws a Domain error. But for some weird reason, you can't access a list index in one go; that is, `{}[1]` is invalid syntax.

`seq` generates a list of values for a function with values in a given range; but in this case, specifying a range of 1 to 0 causes a Domain error, since the end is smaller than the start.

Answer (score 1):

## VBA, 29 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function of length 29 which throws Runtime error  6, (len 28) to STDERR

#### Code

```vba
?CByte(Len(Space(127+128+1)))
```

#### Error

> Run-time error '6':
>
> Overflow

Answer (score 1):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 54 bytes

```
"ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by z"0/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/9fKSq1KN8lsyyzODM/z7WoKL/ISiEzryQ1PbVIIQUqrJBfpJCbn1Kak6@QVKlQpWSg//8/AA)

Throws the 53 byte error `ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero`

### Explanation

`"ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by z"` is a string literal, pushes the error minus 3 bytes.

`0` pushes 0, and `/` attempts to divide the 2nd to last item by the last item, in this case dividing `z` (122) by `0`, which results in a divide by zero error.

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 84 bytes

```
"ValueError: Indices for islice() must be None or an integer: 0 <= x <= sys.maxs"&@@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYuxCoAwEMV@5eEguoizKHRxcHF0r3pKob3CnYJ@fa1LCISsYh2f0R8pFYv1N40iUTpMvLuNFEcUOPXZqxrh1gsrYY5MyMEyHF90Uh5a9AOeH/pqE@yjRWlMSh8)

I personally get this error quite often when screwing around with ASCII art challenges in Braingolf.

Throws a `ValueError: Indices for islice() must be None or an integer: 0 <= x <= sys.maxsize.` error.

### Explanation

`"ValueError: Indices for islice() must be None or an integer: 0 <= x <= sys.max"` is a string literal. It's just the error minus 4 bytes, because the code must be longer than the error.

`&@` then pops and prints the entire stack.

Finally `@` attempts to pop and print an item from the now empty stack. Popping from an empty stack produces the above 83 byte error.

Answer (score 1):

## C++, 26 bytes

```
int main(){div(1,0);} //??
```

Result in Windows:

```
a.exe has stopped working
```

Comment: Actually this should require `#include<cstdlib>`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 26 bytes (error: 25 bytes)

```
a :- a ; a ; a ; a ; a ;a.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/P1HBSlchUcEaHSfqAeX0AA)

This will generate the error: `ERROR: Out of local stack` (which is, as far as I know, the shortest error message that can be generated by SWI-Prolog).

#### Explanation

The above program can be simplified to `a :- a ; a.` (the other `; a`s are here so that the program is longer than the error message).

The above program says:

```
a :-      .        % For a to be true…
     a             % Either a…
       ;           % …or…
         a         % …a must be true
```

This is obviously infinitely recursive, hence why we get an `Out of local stack` error.

However, the following program:

```
a :- a.
```

is also infinitely recursive but will never crash. This is because in that case, **tail recursion optimization** occurs so that the recursive call does not consume memory.

`a :- a ; a.` is also tail recursive; however we have introduced a **disjunction** with `;` which prevents the recursive call from not consuming memory, because Prolog has to remember that there was another choice possible to explore instead of each recursive call.

---

It is possible to generate this same error with other approaches (e.g. using `length(_,1000000000)` to generate a list too big to fit in memory), but this one is probably the coolest looking one.

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy, 69 bytes

```
java.lang.Class.metaClass=Integer.metaClass
Integer.metaClass.plus={1}
```

Error message is:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

I don't know if this will count at 31 bytes, because it will output a lot of line numbers:

```
a​aaaaaa={aaaaaaa()}​;aaaaaaa()
```

Output:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at Script1$_run_closure1.doCall(Script1.groovy:1)
at Script1$_run_closure1.doCall(Script1.groovy)
at Script1$_run_closure1.doCall(Script1.groovy:1)
at Script1$_run_closure1.doCall(Script1.groovy)
...
```

​

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB, <s>52</s> <s>44</s> 43 bytes

Another shorter option is to use a function and not provide enough inputs. For example:

```
qr()%I'm a nice comment to make code longer
```

Gives this 42 byte error:

```
Error using qr
Not enough input arguments.
```

---

This code (or to be fair any similar code:

```
[1 1]*[2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ]
```

Produces the following 51 byte error:

```
Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.
```

It's actually surprisingly tricky in MATLAB because when you run any code with syntax errors the error output includes the line of code you ran - which would put a theoretical lower limit on code size of infinity. Fortunately matrix multiplication errors don't do that.

Comment: I guess [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147560/31516) works in MATLAB too? I'm not sure if all work, but I believe some of them should... :)

Answer (score 1):

## C# (.Net, Mono) 25 bytes

```
class Hi{void There(){_}}
```

Error:

```
error CS1002: ; expected
```

**Note:** Mono error messages include filename and location before them, so if you named the file `P.cs`, you'd get this error:

```
P.cs(1,24): error CS1002: ; expected
```

Since that part depends on the filename and location of text, I didn't include it. However, if you include it (and make the class name longer or something), you end up with a 36 byte error message and 37 byte program. Let me know if I should change it to that.

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC console, <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
?@L*EXP(22)
```

Error message (8 or 9 bytes):

```
Overflow
```

Must be run from the console, otherwise it outputs a line number. Normally errors are formatted like `{error} in {slot}:{line}({func}:{arg})`, but this error isn't caused by a function and doesn't have a line number so only the error name is shown.

`EXP(x)` returns `e^x`, and `e^22` is `3584912846.131588`. This is outside the 32 bit signed integer range of `-2147483648` to `2147483647`. Multiplying a string (`@L`) by this value converts it to an integer, causing an overflow error.

Comment: I'd consider calling the language `SmileBASIC (DIRECT)`, since REPLs and similar environments are considered separate languages.

Comment: Also, you can get the same error with `I%=999E99` for 9 bytes.

Comment: The console isn't a REPL though.

Comment: "REPLs and ***similar environments***" it's close enough that I'd count it, since it is "type in a statement and it runs"

Answer (score 1):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto), 41 bytes

```
                                        &
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOLcn//1@BSKD2/z8A)

Produces `__main__.CodeException: Raised an &rror.`

The error message is 40 chars, so...

Answer (score 1):

## [ed](https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/), 3 bytes

```
?
```

Returns the following error message (2 bytes).

```
?
```

[ed is Turing complete](https://nixwindows.wordpress.com/2018/03/13/ed1-is-turing-complete/), so there shouldn't be issues about whether using it is valid or not. There was a solution in ed before, but it was removed, as there was a concern whether this is a fatal error. I would say, yes, it is, no matter what I did on TIO.run, the execution did not continue after getting an error message. From checking why this happens, it appears that the execution continues only when the code is read from STDIN (REPL mode).

Inspired by https://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed-msg.html

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S035/9@ei@v/fwA)

Note that the output contains `0`, but it's not a part of an error message, rather it's ed displaying file size by default. It can be removed by using `-s` flag. If you try changing the input provided to the program, it will change.

Answer (score 1):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz), 38 bytes

```
1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a4x
```

**Explanation**

```
1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a   # Add 1 to the register 18 times
                                    4x # Set the current opcode to 4
```

The only opcodes accepted by the naz interpreter under any circumstances are **0** (normal operation), **1** (function write), **2** (variable write), and **3** (conditional). Thus, if run from a file with a one-letter filename (e.g. `f.naz`), this program will produce the following 37-byte error:

```
error: invalid opcode
  at f.naz:1:38
```

Answer (score 1):

## COBOL(GNU), 47 bytes

```
PROCEDURE DIVISION. HELLO. HELLO. HELLO. HELLO.
```

Outputs:

`main.cobc: 1: error: PROGRAM-ID header missing`

Assuming filename = main.cobc

Answer (score 1):

## [Setanta](https://try-setanta.ie/), 12 bytes

```
1/0 >--- uwu
```

This produces the 11-byte error message `Roinnt ar 0`.

[Try it here](https://try-setanta.ie/editor/EhEKBlNjcmlwdBCAgICI2OeJCw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Add++](https://github.com/SatansSon/AddPlusPlus), 20 bytes

```
+?
Needed to be long
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/1/bnssvNTUlNUWhJF8hKVUhJz8v/f9/AA)

Error is `Error encountered!` followed by a newline, which is 19 bytes long. This happens because it tries to take input, but fails as there is no input.

Answer (score 0):

## C++ 133 bytes

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    printf("%s", variable);
    return 0;
}
```

Displays the error *(132 bytes)*:

> .code.tio.c: In function ‘main’: .code.tio.c:5:14: error: ‘variable’
>   undeclared (first use in this function) printf("%s", variable);

Comment: The code must be at least one byte longer than the error message.

Comment: This is C++ code!

Comment: @Zacharý Oups! Thanks for the correction!

Comment: And ... you can use a one char file name.

Comment: Would this work? `printf("%s", variable)`=>`printf("%s",variable)`?

Comment: @Zachary polite request, would you mind commenting a bit less? Most posts on this challenge that you've commented multiple times on, your comments could've been condensed into one. The problem is that it pings the post author more times than is necessary and also wastes some space. Thanks :)

Comment: I am sorry about that, I sometimes just realize things after I can't edit the comment anymore. I'll try to organize my thoughts/comments into **one** comment from now on.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 67 bytes

```python
b(h)#This has to be 67 characters. Thus, I'm writing this bullshit.
```

## Error message, 66 bytes

```python
  File ".", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

Note: doesn't work on TIO. Gives a longer error message. Try Python 2.7.13 on a local machine from stdin.

Comment: You can assume a one-char file name.

Comment: Then it gets reduced by 8 bytes.
I think I can get rid of the last '. HAHAHA' then

Comment: why am I getting down votes for this? @Zacharý :(

Comment: I wasn’t the downvoter, but with a local Python 2.7.13 and stdin, I get a 108-byte error: `Traceback (most recent call last):⏎␣␣File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>⏎NameError: name 'b' is not defined⏎`.

Comment: I didn't downvote!

Comment: @AndersKaseorg are we supposed to consider the 'Traceback... last):' portion? I'm asking because the other answer in Python hasn't and hence, neither did I.

Comment: Which other answer in Python? The [tracebacklimit answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/133869/39242) is clever precisely because it suppresses that portion, and the answers based on `SyntaxError`s don’t have a traceback to begin with because the error is from the parser.

Answer (score 0):

## [Brain-Flak (BrainHack)](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), 43 + 3 = 46 bytes

```
([()])()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v9fI1pDM1ZTgwio@///f11HAA)

Produces the error

```
BrainHack: Prelude.chr: bad argument: (-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 24 bytes

```sh
"" #lots of wasted space
```

Outputs `zsh: permission denied:`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P9fSUlBOSe/pFghP02hPLG4JDVFobggMTn1/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## Tcl/Tk, 19

```
pack [text .text 1]
```

outputs

## 18

```
unknown option "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, <s>24</s> 23 bytes

```
@dir                  /
```

Outputs the following <s>23</s> 22-byte error (as calculated by redirecting the output to a file):

```
Invalid switch - "".
```

Edit: Saved 1 byte by not having a switch character at all.

Answer (score 0):

## Tcl, 15

```
if 1234567890/0
```

outputs

```
divide by zero
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ly](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Ly), 77 bytes

```
[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[
```

Outputs:

```
Error occurred during parsing
SyntaxError: unmatched [] brackets in program
```

(note the trailing newline)

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica kernel, 36 bytes

```
ClearAll[f];(*Space Filler*)On[f::f]
```

and the error is 35 bytes:

```
(linebreak)On::none: Message f::f not found.(linebreak)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [4](http://esolangs.org/wiki/4), 14 bytes

```
3.141592653589
```

All `4` programs must start with `3.` and end with `4`.

Provides as error (when run with the provided python interpreter)

```
Code invalid.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Applesoft BASIC, 14 bytes

```
SYNTAX ERROR??
```

Output:

```
?SYNTAX ERROR
```

Answer (score 0):

## [ExtraC](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/extrac), 21 bytes

```
Invalid character: :
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S60oKUpM/v/fM68sMSczRSE5IxHIL0ktslKwUvj/HwA)

If you remove the space after the second `:`it is a error quine

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript 79 bytes

```
clear(this);
a=0;
typein:2: TyperError: attempt to run compile-and-go script on a
```

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/61126/63187 ripped from

Answer (score 0):

## C++ (MinGW + GCC + Windows), compile time, 38 <del>39</del> <del>46</del> bytes

According to OP's comment, it seems OK to assume the file is stored in a designated path. The code needs to be saved in a 8-byte location such as `D:\a.cpp`.

```
#if 1/*aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa*/
```

Error message:

```
D:\a.cpp:1:0: error: unterminated #if
```

The principle should work on other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 47 Bytes

`<?php echo 'program including divide by 0',1/0;`

produces:

`PHP Warning:  Division by zero in - on line 1` plus a newline.

Comment: -1: That´s not a fatal error.

Comment: Actually, you're right. Warnings aren't fatal. In a quick search I haven't found the right setting yet...

Comment: Try https://akrabat.com/convert-php-warnings-and-notices-into-fatal-errors/

Comment: I´d give +1 for the exact counting, but my vote is locked.

Answer (score 0):

## Vim, 19 bytes?

```
:print "ex command
```

With a trailing newline, this prints the current line to the messages window. If the buffer is empty, it shows `E749: empty buffer` instead. The `"` starts a comment.

I'm an very unsure how to count the number of bytes both in the input and error message. The command can be run as `vim +"print \"ex command"` (17 bytes?), but this adds an additional line to the error message: `Error detected while processing command line:` (total 62 bytes?).

Alternatively, the command can be put in a file and run the the following hack to trick Vim it is user input: `cat cmd.vim - | vim --not-a-term`. Without `--not-a-term` Vim writes `Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal`.

I didn't count the error message length including a newline since Vim won't write a newline to the screen; it uses ncurses or similar to directly draw at specific coordinates.

There is one potentially shorter error message: `E572: Exit code %d`. It can be triggered by `:tcl`, but I'll leave it to someone who has `+tcl` enabled.

Answer (score 0):

## ><>, 26 Bytes

Code: `"we'refinehereuntilthis!"z`

Error: `Something smells fishy...`

All ><> errors are Something smells fishy...

Comment: @HyperNeutrino already posted this. https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/133840/shortest-error-message?#133844

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 13 bytes

```
prompt(alert(
```

Error produced (12 bytes):

```
Expected ')'
```

Comment: Which browser? Firefox gives: SyntaxError: expected expression, got end of script

Answer (score 0):

## Julia 0.6 (REPL/-e), 20 bytes

```
print(factorial(-9))
```

produces:

```
ERROR: DomainError:
```

(assuming stacktraces don't count) which is 19 bytes.

---

Older answer, 22 bytes:

```
println(Int(Inf)+0123)
```

Produces

```
ERROR: InexactError()
```

which is 21 bytes.

---

Trivial answer, 7 bytes (probably falls short of "The error message may not be generated by the program itself, such as Python's raise" requirement):

```
error()
```

produces

```
ERROR:
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 40 bytes

```
A Reference Error: Undefined variable!!!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP3/31EhKDUttSg1LzlVwbWoKL/ISiE0LyU1LTMvNUWhLLEoMzEpJ1VRUfH/fwA)

Message (39 bytes): `Reference Error: Undefined variable "A"`

Answer (score 0):

## F#, 29 bytes code, 28 bytes error message

```
let [<EntryPoint>] main a=1/0
```

Generates the runtime Exception message:

```
Attempted to divide by zero.
```

+5 bytes thanks to [lukass](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/25290/lukass).

Comment: The question requires an error message shorter than the program:

> Write the shortest program that, when compiled or executed, produces **a fatal error message smaller than the program itself.**

Comment: I've no idea why, but I read the question as "longer". Damn. Now that I think about it, that makes more sense as a challenge too...

Comment: Golfing the combined length of a program and its _longer_ error message would actually be interesting. Write a longer program to generate a shorter message is a cool tradeoff :)

Answer (score 0):

## Go, 36 bytes

```
package verylongnamednonmainpackage;
```

Produces:

```
go run: cannot run non-main package
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Coconut](http://coconut-lang.org/), 48 bytes

Code:

```
+
CoconutParsererErrorr: parsing failed (line 1)
```

Prints error (47 bytes):

```
CoconutParseError: parsing failed (line 1)
  +
```

with a trailing newline

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85Pzs8rLfn/X5vLGcIMSCwqTi1KLXItKsovKrJSKADyM/PSFdISM3NSUxQ0cjLzUhUMNf//BwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Loader](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Loader), 50 bytes

```
load t
This is line not executed because of error.
```

Assumptions:

- The program is run from a file with a one-byte name
- The module named `t` does not exist.

The error message (assuming you run from a module named `m`) is:

```
Error: module t does not exist (module m, line 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C# .NET](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/), 59 bytes

```
public class P{static void Main(){int je=0;int iee=je/je;}}
```

[Try Online](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS5O/v@/oDQpJzNZITknsbhYIaC6uCSxBMgty89MUfBNzMzT0KzOzCtRyEq1NbAGMTJTU22zUvWzUq1ra///BwA)
Produces the following error (58 bytes):

```
System.DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero.
```

(**NOTE:** I am not counting in the stacktrace that the .NET Compiler generates)

Answer (score 0):

### Python, 30 bytes

```python
import math as ma; ma.sqrt(-1)
```

Error: `ValueError: math domain error` (29 bytes)

Answer (score 0):

## GNU Smalltalk, 26 bytes

Create a source file `_` with underscores:

```
__________________________
```

Running `gst _`, the error is 25 bytes including ␤:

```
_:1: expected expression
```

Underscore was originally mapped to `←`, the assignment operator prior to `:=`.

Answer (score 0):

### C, Bionic libc (Android, Termux), 16 characters

```
main(){free(1);}
```

### Output, 8 characters (including newline)

```
Aborted
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 35 bytes

Pretty simple.

```
print(a)###########################
```

Prints out an undeclared variable then adds a comment to make sure that the error message (`NameError: name 'a' is not defined`) is shorter than the actual code. I could've probably done better.

Answer (score 0):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.ph) ([wspace 0.3](https://web.archive.org/web/20150717140342/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/download.php)), 19 bytes

```
SSSSL
SLS
TSTS
TLST
LLL
```

Error: `w: divide by zero` (18 bytes)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/XwEIuICQEwSBFBcX1///AA)

The zero divisor error is the shortest error message produced by the [wspace 0.3](https://web.archive.org/web/20150717140342/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/download.php) reference interpreter (see the [yspace](https://github.com/andrewarchi/yspace/tree/main/tests) project for a survey of other errors). Using `mod` in place of `div` would yield an equivalent result. The reference interpreter was written in Haskell, so arithmetic operations are evaluated lazily and it will not panic with `divide by zero` unless the illegal value is used by an eager instruction—`printi` in this case. To reach the minimum byte count, `push 0` is written as `SSSSL` and `end` is appended.

```
push 0
dup
div
printi
end
```

Renaming `wspace` to `w` gives a shorter error message.

```sh
$ ln -s ~/bin/wspace w
$ ./w codegolf/shortest_error.ws
w: divide by zero
$ ./w shortest_error.ws 2>| wc -c
      18
$ wc -c < shortest_error.ws
      19
```

*(This solution is part of the [ws-challenges](https://github.com/andrewarchi/ws-challenges) repo)*

Answer (score 0):

## [Raku (Perl 6) (rakudo)](https://raku.org), 38 bytes

```perl
die#iaj zav; xbsio la, n v km l s zioa
```

When run using `raku -e`, this produces the 37-byte output

```
Died
  in block <unit> at -e line 1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kKDG7dMGCpaUlaboWN9VSMlOVMxOzFKoSy6wVKpKKM_MVchJ1FPIUyhSycxVyFIoVqjLzEyGqoZpgmgE)

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 38 bytes

```
222222222222222222222222222222222222[x
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIiLCIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjJbeCIsIiIsIiIsIjMuNC4yIl0=)

RuntimeException: Too many recursions

Answer (score 0):

## YASEPL, 38 bytes

```
=p/0+000000000000000000000000000000000
```

error message:

```
ERROR 8 divide by 0:(

located at /0
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 67 bytes

```go
package main
func main(){var f string = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BgqWlJWm6FjedCxKTsxPTUxVyEzPzuNJK85LBLA3N6rLEIoU0heKSosy8dAVbBaVEHECpFmIU1ESYyQA)

Gives the following error (66 bytes):

```
# command-line-arguments
../code.go:2:17: f declared and not used
```

Answer (score 0):

## Swift, 46 bytes

```swift
let message = "what do you want it to do?"
let
```

[Try the fiddle!](https://swiftfiddle.com/7m6267bd4zf7vgz7tiqyvotb4m)

### Error, 45 bytes (when compiled from standard input)

```
<stdin>:2:4: error: expected pattern
let
   ^
```