# Last digit large number

Tags: code-golf, math

For a given list of number \$[x_1, x_2, x_3, ..., x_n]\$ find the last digit of \$x_1 ^{x_2 ^ {x_3 ^ {\dots ^ {x_n}}}}\$
Example:

```
[3, 4, 2] == 1
[4, 3, 2] == 4
[4, 3, 1] == 4
[5, 3, 2] == 5
```

Because \$3 ^ {(4 ^ 2)} = 3 ^ {16} = 43046721\$.

Because \$4 ^ {(3 ^ 2)} = 4 ^ {9} = 262144\$.

Because \$4 ^ {(3 ^ 1)} = 4 ^ {3} = 64\$.

Because \$5 ^ {(3 ^ 2)} = 5 ^ {9} = 1953125\$.

Rules:

This is code golf, so the answer with the fewest bytes wins.

If your language has limits on integer size (ex. \$2^{32}-1\$) n will be small enough that the sum will fit in the integer.

Input can be any reasonable form (stdin, file, command line parameter, integer, string, etc).

Output can be any reasonable form (stdout, file, graphical user element that displays the number, etc).

Saw on code wars.

Comment: One question I have: In your post you only talk about `number`s. Do you mean positive integers exclusively? That is I feel how it was interpreted.

Comment: Is taking the input in reverse reasonable? Can the input be zero?

Comment: (i. e. can any input value be zero). Do we need to handle the one-value case?

Comment: I *think* you intend for the limit to be on sum of terms, and thus routines that calculate the actual sum then mod it should fail. E.g. the input `[999999,213412499,34532599,4125159,53539,54256439,353259,4314319,5325329,1242149,142219,1243219,14149,1242149,124419,999999999]` is valid and the result should be `1` If so, this needs to be made clearer in the question as you have upvoted answers that do not solve this (hint - move the `mod` inside the loop). Perhaps add some examples that make this clear.

Comment: Actually the result from my example is `9`. The digit reduction scheme necessary to implement this is a lot more interesting than the actual answers this problem has garnered.

Comment: @NeilSlater you can only do `%10` on the last iteration. Consider `2**3` vs `2**13`.

Comment: @NieDzejkob: `2**3 % 10 == 2**7 % 10 == 2**11 % 10`. Other last digits have different patterns. This knowledge is necessary to complete the puzzle and cope with arrays of numbers that would otherwise be too large to process. As far as I can tell, none of the answers here actually cope with the original problem as posed on Code Wars.

Comment: Dear OP, we need more test cases.

Comment: In fact the solution for `[999999,213412499,34532599,4125159,53539,54256439,353259,4314319,5325329,1242149,142219,1243219,14149,1242149,124419,999999999]` is straightforward, base ends with 9, so last digit is 9 when first exponent is odd, 1 when exponent is even. I would really like a codegolf that limits _inputs_ to the available integer range, and not the full exponential.

Comment: @NeilSlater Because nobody requires us that the answers need to work in any time limit. Who cares about that, only short code matters.

Comment: @user202729 I did not mention any time limit. The question *does* in fact imply that you need to be able to cope with very large interim values - in the title. Also the Code Wars version does require it (it's the whole point of the challenge - just taking a modulus at the end is trivial and doesn't solve anything meaningful). And it is still possible to golf the code to do this, just it would be longer than the answers given. However, the question was not worded clearly, and now there are lots of solutions that don't work with that constraint. So the chance to change it here is gone.

Comment: @NeilSlater That is why initially I voted to close this as "unclear what you're asking" (not sure if I actually voted to close), because I had the same thought -- this should have time limit, but OP didn't include any. However if it does include a time limit **it needs to be explicitly stated in the challenge** with all the machine specification details and possible inputs, because otherwise we cannot be clear what the time limit is.

Comment: See also: [What's a general algorithm/technique to find the last digit of a nested exponential?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2713356)

Answer (score 15):

## JavaScript (ES7), 22 bytes

Limited to \$2^{53}-1\$.

```javascript
a=>eval(a.join`**`)%10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i61LDFHI1EvKz8zL0FLK0FT1dDgf3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RppGtLGOgomOglGspqaCvr6CIReaNFDOGCFtgl3aEJe0KYpuUwWF/wA)

Comment: What on earth, why does this work?!

Comment: @komali_2: `**` is JavaScript's exponentiation operator. The rest is pretty straightforward.

Comment: @komali_2 ``a.join`**` `` is equivalent to `a.join(['**'])` and `['**']` is coerced to `'**'` by the `join` method.

Comment: I think that OP intends that the limit is on the *sum* of values, in which case this does not solve the problems as posed.

Comment: Sorry for the basic question, what part of this is retrieving the last digit?

Comment: @AJFaraday the %10 at the end. When dividing any number by 10, the remainder (the modulus) will always be the last digit, so `n % 10` will return the last digit of `n`

Comment: @Mayube doh.jpg Of course, I should have spotted that.

Comment: `(a=>eval(a.join\`**\`)%10)([2, 53, 53])` -> `NaN`

Answer (score 13):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 25 bytes

```r
Reduce(`^`,scan(),,T)%%10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Pyg1pTQ5VSMhLkGnODkxT0NTRydEU1XV0OC/MZcJlxHXfwA)

Comment: Not sure what people liked so much about this answer.

Comment: I personally like to see `Reduce` being used.

Answer (score 10):

### Haskell, 19 bytes

```
(`mod`10).foldr1(^)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzXyMhNz8lwdBAUy8tPyelyFAjTvN/bmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JgopCmkK0sY6JjlHs/3/JaTmJ6cX/dZMLCgA)

Answer (score 9):

## HP 49G RPL, 36.5 bytes

Run it in APPROX mode (but enter the program in EXACT mode). Takes input on the stack with the first element deepest in the stack, as integers or reals.

```
WHILE DEPTH 1 - REPEAT ^ END 10 MOD
```

It straightforwardly exponentiates on the stack as in Sophia's solution until there is one value left, then takes it mod 10 to get the last digit.

The reason I use APPROX for computation is because 0.0^0.0 = 1 (when they are both reals), but 0^0 = ? (when they are both integers). APPROX coerces all integers to reals, so the input is fine with either. However, I use EXACT to enter the program because 10 (integer) is stored digit-by-digit, and is 6.5 bytes, but 10.0 (real) is stored as a full real number, and is 10.5 bytes. I also avoid using RPL's reduce (called STREAM) because it introduces an extra program object, which is 10 bytes of overhead. I already have one and don't want another.

Limited to the precision of an HP 49G real (12 decimal digits)

-10 bytes after empty list -> 1 requirement was removed.

-2 bytes by taking input on stack.

Comment: Hey, could you explain how the bytecount is calculated? Just curious how that language uses [nibbles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble).

Comment: @JungHwanMin The HP 49G uses a 4-bit processor and BCD arithmetic, since it's a calculator. Internally most commands are transformed into 2.5 byte pointers to the routines they represent, to save space. Small numbers (0-9) are also transformed in this way.

Comment: The Saturn processor is actually pretty fun to work with. A _long_ time ago, I wrote [this port of BurgerTime](https://www.hpcalc.org/details/472) (in assembly) for the HP 48G(X). It was later [ported to the 49G](https://www.hpcalc.org/details/4384). Good memories!

Answer (score 7):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), <strike>17</strike> 15 bytes

```
1[^z1<M]dsMxzA%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@b6xgomD03zA6rsrQxjc2pdi3ospR9X/BfwA)

Takes input from the stack, outputs to the stack. Very straightforward implementation - exponentiates until only one value is left on the stack and mod for the last digit.

Thanks to brhfl for saving two bytes!

Comment: You can golf one byte by changing `10%` to `A%`, and one more byte by not checking stack depth twice - just put a `1` atop the stack before executing since n^1==n: `1[^z1<M]dsMxA%`

Comment: Good ideas! I had no idea dc would let me use `A` as a literal while set to decimal input. Thank you @brhfl!

Comment: @SophiaLechner This trick works for all input bases: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77728/11259

Answer (score 6):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 5 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to cole!

```
10|^/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVmyrp2CgYKVg8N/QoCZO/78ml5KegnqarZ66go5CrZVCWjEXV2pyRr5CmoKxgomCUcV/AA)

Comment: Does `10|^/` not work?

Comment: @cole Of course it works, thanks!

Comment: Finally, a challenge where J beats Jelly!

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
.«mθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/e/6X@/Q6txzO/7/jzbWUTDRUTCKBQA)

**Explanation**

```
.«     # fold
  m    # power
   θ   # take the last digit
```

Comment: As far as I am aware, stack-based languages can assume the input is present on the stack instead of STDIN or alternatives, so something like [this](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/W9sYhT8X@/Q6txzO/7/BwA) should work for 4 bytes (alternatively, just place `E` in the header).

Comment: [Relevant Meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8493/59487).

Comment: I have fixed this issue in the [latest commit](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/commit/fe1ab180c0f4157c25db3cacea99136454b2fd1d) for future use.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder: Right! I should have remembered that. So rarely need to though with implicit input. Thanks :)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Uh, I'm not sure if that's what the meta really means. What is a "function" in 05AB1E? I think it should simply be a string, since you can assign it to a variable, and can be eval-ed with `.V`. `.«mθ` looks more like a snippet, since, by itself, you can't assign it to a variable for later reuse. Well, Adnan now fixed the issue, but eh.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I think the Meta answer uses *function* as a generic term. Anyway, if you disagree I'll add an answer to Default I/Os that allows this, because it seems perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 16 bytes

```
Power@##~Mod~10&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2ar8T8gvzy1yEFZuc43P6XO0EDtv6Y1V0BRZl5JdLWycq2uXRpQLlbNwcGhmour2lhHwURHwahWB8g20lEAckFkLRdX7X8A)

Answer (score 5):

## Pure [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) (builtins only - no external utilities), 21

```bash
echo $[${1//,/**}%10]
```

Input is given on the command line as a comma-separated list.

Bash integers are subject to normal signed integer limits for 64- and 32-bit versions.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19BJVql2lBfX0dfS6tW1dAg9v///8Y6JjpGAA)

Comment: `^` is bitwise XOR, which is why you're getting `5` out of the test case instead of the correct `1`. You'll need to add a byte to switch to `**`

Comment: @SophiaLechner Yes - of course - good catch!  Not sure how that `^` crept in - I had `**` in previous iterations of my dev cycle.

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 14 bytes

```perl6
{([**] $_)%10}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1uplmr7v1ojWksrVkElXlPV0KD2vzVXcWKlglqqhoaxjomOkabmfwA)

Uses the reduction meta square brackets with the operator **, modulo 10.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/) and [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 30 bytes

```python
lambda N:eval('**'.join(N))%10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY1NCsIwGAXX5hTfRpKUEGyjIIV6hFxAXURqMCV/JEEopWeP7cbtG2ZenMsneFH18KhWudeoQPbvr7IENw3mUzCeSEqP7akaF0MqkOeMdEggwXhwKpJcEs/RmsJ2xnMZjac9OsRkfCH4vqxPGG6wrJhvnlPbxuCfZqD3A1oFnKFDLbpcBbSd@AE)

The input `N` is expected to be an iterable object over *string representations of number literals*.

Answer (score 4):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 30 bytes

```julia
first∘digits∘x->foldl(^,x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/8/LbOouORRx4yUzPTMkmIgo0LXLi0/JyVHI06nQvO/Q3FGfrmCBn5VmhrRhjpGOsaxmlzEqjfWMdExAqonWkNSZrqSsbGxoZIOmAWjjZRiNf8DAA)

This is an anon function
∘ is the composition operator.
It is multiple bytes

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, <s>41</s> 47 bytes

Size increase due to handling of any 0 in the input array, which needs extra consideration. Thanks to `rewritten`

```
->a{a.reverse.inject{|t,n|n<2?n:n**(t%4+4)}%10}
```

This is solved as I believe the original source intended, i.e. for very large exponentiations that will not fit into language native integers - the restriction is that the array will sum into `2**32-1`, not that the interim calculations are also guaranteed to fit. In fact that would seem to be the point of the challenge on Code Wars. Although Ruby's native integers can get pretty big, they cannot cope with the example below processed naively with a %10 at the end

E.g.

Input: `[999999,213412499,34532597,4125159,53539,54256439,353259,4314319,5325329,1242149,142219,1243219,14149,1242149,124419,999999999]`

Output:
`9`

Comment: Impressive. By spending a 4 more bytes, you can also cope with much higher towers: replace `n**(t%4+4)` with `n**((t-1)%4+1)` so you get `n**1` instead of `n**5` etc. Kudos for the observation that at any stage 4 would be a good cycle.

Comment: There is an issue if the sequence has 0s

Comment: @rewritten: Good spot! I'll have to think about that. In theory the sequence should be forced to terminate 2 steps before the first zero.

Comment: Indeed, but that will require a lot more code, exactly 6 more bytes: `n<2?n:` before `n**`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-h`, <s>7</s> 6 bytes

If input can be taken in reverse order then the first character can be removed.

Limited to `2**53-1`.

```
Ôr!p ì
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=1HIhcCDs&input=WzMsNCwyXQotaA==)

---

### Explanation

```
Ô          :Reverse the array
 r         :Reduce by
  !p       :  Raising the current element to the power of the current total, initially the first element
     ì     :Split to an array of digits
           :Implicitly output the last element
```

Comment: I got the exact same answer without the flag so this looks like the optimal way for now.

Comment: @Nit: until it's confirmed we can take input in reverse :)

Comment: @Oliver Yeah, but you're still using a flag. Personally I think the byte count without flags is the most accurate scoring result.

Comment: @Nit Shouldn't a flag add 3 bytes by meta consensus?

Comment: @LegionMammal978, [not any more](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/58974).

Comment: Ah, okay. It's a bit tricky trying to search stuff on Meta.

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>50</s> 44 bytes

*-6 bytes from @Shaggy*

```php
<?=eval("return ".join('**',$argv).";")%10?>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRoKCSWJReZhttrGOiYxRrrWBvBxS3TS1LzNFQKkotKS3KU1DSy8rPzNNQ19JS1wGr1tRTslbSVDU0ACr@/x8A)

Comment: btw, you can use [`join()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.join.php) to shave off 3 bytes because it's an alias of `implode()`, but I don't agree with how you're passing in input, you're just setting an array before your script is called. I think you should parse `$argv` or `$argn`.

Comment: You're supposed to return the last digit, not the whole thing.

Comment: [44 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRoKCSWJReZhttrGOiYxRrrWBvBxS3TS1LzNFQKkotKS3KU1DSy8rPzNNQ19JS1wGr1tRTslbSVDU0ACr@/x8A)

Comment: Well, if this kind of input is valid, then it can be even shorter: [40 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRoKCSWJReZhttrGOiYxRrrWBvBxRPLUvM0VBKTc7IV1DSy8rPzNNQ19JS1wEr1dRTUjU0sFbStP7///@//IKSzPy84v@6eQA)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
`.gGm}T%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/QS/dPbc2RPX//2hjHQUTHQWjWAA)

Comment: I think you mean [`...gGm}10%`](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/QS/dPbfW0ED1//9oYx0FEx0Fo1gA) (or something golfier).

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 56

- Saved 4 bytes thanks to @JonathanFrech

Recursive function `r()` called from macro `f` - normal stack limits apply.

```c
R;r(int*n){R=pow(*n,n[1]?r(n+1):1);}
#define f(n)r(n)%10
```

Input given as a zero-terminated int array.  This is under the assumption that none of the x<sub>n</sub> are zero.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzLCoMwFET3@YqLIiQ2Fl@r2seHWBchvgJ6laitIP5609hNZzfnMCODRkrjKpTdUlZwneZSDef2Tv6oF3NridFU4ewj23Q1LxphHN7UR455VDw0xVPELhHLduKWVa2wgpois5x5UWjsEnqhEI4PELqRHGQrNPi@LS9GNgI2h1zzAm6wJRxSDjGHcM/IT47a6po6XvlEh9v7lbGM7MYkPOXxR9adaCYTdP0X)

Comment: `) r(` -> `)r(`.

Comment: Also, if you want to use UB, you could golf `r(int*n){return pow` to `R;r(int*n){R=pow`.

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 84 bytes

```cs
a=>{int i=a.Length-1,j=a[i];for(;i-->0;)j=(int)System.Math.Pow(a[i],j);return j%10;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZE9a8MwEIbn@FfcUrBA/u4HVLWXQqcEAh06GA9CkR2ZRDKS3LQY/3ZX@WghtBQPd9zwPPceHDMBU5pPAGxHjYG1Vo2mew9gcAVgLLWCwbsSG1hRIX1jtZBNWQHVjUEn5kwCvH4ay/fhSy/Zk5C2rLDrRZ1PNC8GN4LIabjksrHbIMFtTktRkVppn4ggKGKC2tx3GLrsWVG7Ddfq4B853CKiue21hPYmick4kYW3uJDPShq14@GbFpYvheR@7Ut@KKshw7c4HREiEEXAPzrOLN88QjJDTfHdX2o6Q3WZOPut3s86@CzCtfowJ/XbvFYzbxFF/8tw/FZc/eRKZcH0Xae023B67uj6OH0B)

- -7 bytes thanks to @raznagul

Comment: You can save some bytes by removing the brackers around `a` and by combining the loop condition with the decrement (`for(var i=a.Lengt-1;i-->0;)`). But `using`-statement must be included in he byte count.

Comment: @raznagul: sorry, I'm pretty new to code-golf in C#, is it ok now ?

Comment: No problem. Yes this is fine now.

Comment: You can save 3 more bytes by using a new variable to hold the result and remove most of the index access to the array: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZE9a8MwEIbn@FfcUrBA/u4HVLWXQqcEAh06GA9CkR2ZRDKS3LQY/3ZX@WghtBQPd9zwPPceHDMBU5pPAGxHjYG1Vo2mew9gcAVgLLWCwbsSG1hRIX1jtZBNWQHVjUEn5kwCvH4ay/fhSy/Zk5C2rLDrRZ1PNC8GN4LIabjksrHbIMFtTktRkVppn4ggKGKC2tx3GLrsWVG7Ddfq4B853CKiue21hPYmick4kYW3uJDPShq14@GbFpYvheR@7Ut@KKshw7c4HREiEEXAPzrOLN88QjJDTfHdX2o6Q3WZOPut3s86@CzCtfowJ/XbvFYzbxFF/8tw/FZc/eRKZcH0Xae023B67uj6OH0B)

Comment: @raznagul: great !

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```apl
10|*⌿
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///39CgRutRz/7/j/qmPmqboPGot8/oUVczkBcc5AwkQzw8gzWB9H9jBRMFIwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-h`, 7 bytes

```
OvUqp)ì
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/378stLBA8/Ca//@jTXUUjHUUjGK5uHQzAA)

### Explanation:

```
OvUqp)ì
Ov   )    // Japt eval:
   q      //   Join
  U       //   Input with
    p     //   Power method
      ì   // Split into an array of numbers
-h        // Return the last number
```

Comment: Weird, that wouldn't work for me.

Comment: [6 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///CUIsUChcNr/v@PNtVRMNZRMIrl4tLNAAA)

Comment: @Shaggy [:P](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168271/61613)

Comment: Ah, for Jaysis' sake! :\ That's happening more & more often!

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
U*@/DṪ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z9Uy0Hf5eHOVf///4821lEw0VEwigUA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.6/), 55 bytes

```python
p=lambda l,i=-1:not l or f'{l[0]**int(p(l[1:],0))}'[i:]
```

Older versions

```python
p=lambda l,i=-1:len(l)and f'{l[0]**int(p(l[1:],0))}'[i:]or 1    (60 bytes)
```

Comment: Wouldn't that have to be `p=lambda...`? Python can't handle recursive anonymous lambdas, so if you need your function to be named, it needs to be part of your solution, and the naming counts towards your byte count for code-golf challenges.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>45</s> 43 bytes

```python
lambda x:reduce(lambda b,a:a**b,x[::-1])%10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYrRCoMgGEav8yn@GynDxqwGQ2gv0rywZUwoi1836uldwi4OH4fvbEd4r66OU/eMs16GUcMu0Yyflyn@PnAtdVkOfO@lrIRiVFyjXbYVA/jDk2lFmK0zYF3yiw@jdZJkGhE6MF89F@lmJNvQugA5RageQH0OFIqz4jClYSz2DW95rUgvTm73hou6UT8)

Answer (score 2):

## Excel VBA, 60 bytes

An anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from range `[A1:XFD1]`

```vb
s=1:For i=-[Count(1:1)]To-1:s=Cells(1,-i)^s:Next:?Right(s,1)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
üT(Çó╖⌐
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=81542880a2b7a9&i=[3,4,2]&a=1&m=2)

Algorithm like in [my Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168276/78123)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>76</s> 75 bytes

- Saved a byte thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat); golfing `o<=O` to `O/o`.

```c
o(int*O){O=_(O)%10;}_(O,o,Q)int*O;{for(o=Q=1;*O>=0&&_(O+1)/Q++;o*=*O);O=o;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxBCsIwEEXX9hiFlplkio26G6ZXCFmLiEQqXdiR0l3I2WN09@H99@LwirEUhWXdjcfk5Q4eOzdyroOUAv4Jp1k3UAni2PhJxr6v3Do8BmtZjVSZvSjn8n4sK2D6bFWcoe2eLSn8@tcbpuZwpgudGhpcRqzvLw) Takes input as an `int` pointer to a `-1`-terminated list of integers.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>24</s> 20 bytes

```ruby
->a{eval(a*'**')%10}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6xOrUsMUcjUUtdS0tdU9XQoPZ/gUJadLSxjomOUWzsfwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 14 bytes

```
q~_,({~#]}*~A%
```

Should work for any input, since CJam isn't limited to 64 bit integers

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v7AuXkejuk45tlarzlH1//9oYwUTBaNYAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 47 bytes

```python
f=lambda x,y=1:f(x[:-1],x[-1]**y)if x else y%10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYzLCoMwFETXzVfcTTGRVBptoQj2R8SFRUNvyYskiwTx222cxSzmcMbl@LWmOw45qFl/lhkSz4PoJU1jfxMTT2Ppus4MJSRYVVghX8X9QO2sjxByINL6gtCAnh0N0TfBKYz8ZE2ICxrWk4vzaCKtxm2fYHjDtldN8fRcNg5V87NoaGIcJFUYIj2visATO3N08ICWCPJ8dSDa7g8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 161 bytes

Includes +1 for `-r`

```
([][()]){({}[()]<({}<(({}))>[()]){({}<(({})<({}<>)({<({}[()])><>({})<>}{}<><{}>)>)>[()])}{}{}>)}{}({}((()()()()()){})(<>))<>{(({})){({}[()])<>}{}}{}<>([{}()]{})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY07DsMwDEP3nIQcsrQdBV3E8JAOBYoUHbIKPrtK20khQL8nUs9je3/X12fbM1FqASsD0XpjqgYl0v9gLgZyIuy8pZsP4K0Ti@b0U6ZNH5V0AYBXUALIRqqYf67X02dYoUjEKpr5WO7LLdfjBw)

The example `[3, 4, 2]` takes longer than 60 seconds, so the TIO link uses `[4, 3, 2]`.

The `-r` can be removed if input can be taken in reverse order for a byte count of 160.

```
# Push stack size -1
([][()])

# While there are 2 numbers on the stack
{({}[()]<

    # Duplicate the second number on the stack (we're multiplying this number by itself)
    ({}<(({}))>[()])

    # For 0 .. TOS
    {({}<

        # Copy TOS
        (({})<

        # Multiple Top 2 numbers
        ({}<>)({<({}[()])><>({})<>}{}<><{}>)

        # Paste the old TOS
        >)

    # End for (and clean up a little)
    >[()])}{}{}

# End While (and clean up)
>)}{}

# Mod 10
({}((()()()()()){})(<>))<>{(({})){({}[()])<>}{}}{}<>([{}()]{})
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 32 bytes

```
a->fold((x,y)->y^x,Vecrev(a))%10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8D9R1y4tPydFQ6NCp1JT164yrkInLDW5KLVMI1FTU9XQ4H9BUWZeiUaaRrSxjomOUaym5n8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Z80Golf](https://github.com/lynn/z80golf), 36 bytes

```
00000000: cd03 80f5 30fa f1f1 57f1 280d 4f41 15af  ....0...W.(.OA..
00000010: 8110 fd47 1520 f818 ef7a d60a 30fc c60a  ...G. ...z..0...
00000020: cd00 8076                                ...v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY6xDsIwDESlsvEVNzJZdpo2FhsTIyNzlGAWJDaG/nzqKN05yacbzk@3Kb@/H2uND11RKs9QtgUzW4aJCZbkFpQrokWBLNkAcrHfky70uBGdB0GcoSIMqzF5NXhSUbwsZdSVc@cWlJ46407dt8E6GGHsYN@RVvyRv/1aO03TDg)

[Brute-force test harness](https://tio.run/##hZJbi9swEIWf419xMBTbqVeRnZsJTaFPfezLQh@yS1FsaePEsYylLMm2/e3pKE4b77LQAQ3DaOY7x5fmZDe6Hp/P5b7RrYU2Mcxh3bQ6l8Z4XiEVrDQ2F0aaMFp4A6VblChrtKJ@kmEap9OZ6w9OpawKrMpHqt3Q9r2hQaloezik20@g5qX3bzXG1m0PZGVkd7Nupdi5yhF37xJ7SEq7PrcPjrG7sHvwG/2Cr/p43PhvBShVr1TeyMSoOqW@1FXL04aZk7FyH/rHY4G7Fp/B1mXNbKn9yPOcEeuMvH7rz6LCsvdlWL6R@e6HPtjmYMOVvxZm48fw73KXm7asrULg4yOCgG11WYcqeHg4/rxf8PT4O4CTub/IRDTjB/iFkW7s6CXjT7pSI9Pmf@ubvcdoxenJhDGSfhVJnsJgOLzy96IJjW1jIkYRPiDhWC5BM@czv8YCecHHyLiaYsyVgEpUgumcUprxAhM1SZBMhQIYBafznYXs2xfGvI6QECNLCK2KyZxGU6qyJINUc4FixoXj5shd5RhfmcsvHevKSDsfnHzMZ/hP0NrzHw)

Takes input as raw bytes. Limited to 2**8-1.

### Explanation

```
input:
    call $8003    ;      the input bytes
    push af       ; push                 on the stack
    jr nc, input  ;                                   until EOF
    pop af        ; the last byte is going to be pushed twice
    pop af
outer:
    ld d, a       ; d = exponentiation loop counter, aka the exponent
    pop af        ; pop the new base off the stack
    jr z, output  ; The flags are being pushed and popped together with the
                  ; accumulator. Since the Z flag starts as unset and no
                  ; instruction in the input loop modifies it, the Z flag is
                  ; going to be unset as long as there is input, so the jump
                  ; won't be taken. After input is depleted, a controlled stack
                  ; underflow will occur. Since SP starts at 0, the flags
                  ; register will be set to the $cd byte from the very beginning
                  ; of the program. The bit corresponding to the Z flag happens
                  ; to be set in that byte, so the main loop will stop executing
    ld c, a       ; C = current base
    ld b, c       ; B = partial product of the exponentiation loop
    dec d         ; if the exponent is 2, the loop should only execute once, so
                  ; decrement it to adjust that
pow:
    xor a         ; the multiplication loop sets A to B*C and zeroes B in the
mul:              ; process, since it's used as the loop counter
    add c         ; it's definitely not the fastest multiplication algorithm,
    djnz mul      ; but it is the smallest
    ld b, a       ; save the multiplication result as the partial product
    dec d         ; jump back to make the next iteration of either
    jr nz, pow    ; the exponentiation loop or the main loop, adjusting the
    jr outer      ; loop counter in the process
output:           ; after all input is processed, we jump here. We've prepared
    ld a, d       ; to use the result as the next exponent, so copy it back to A
mod:              ; simple modulo algorithm:
    sub 10        ;            subtract ten
    jr nc, mod    ; repeatedly              until you underflow,
    add 10        ; then undo the last subtraction by adding ten
    call $8000    ; output the result
    halt          ; and exit
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, without limitation on very high exponential towers, 142 bytes

```ruby
def d(b,h,*t)
h=h%b
return h if !t[0]
l=b.times.find_index{|i|h**(i+2)%b==h} unless h*h==b
l ?l==0?h:h**d(l+1,*t)%b:[1,h,0][[t[0],2].min]
end
```

This code operates a reduction at each step so every single exponentiation is done on very small numbers. It is able to deal with almost arbitrarily high exponential towers without using arbitrary precision, all is done within a very small integer range, the highest integer used at any point is `9**9`.

The function must be called with an initial base, for the examples it would be

> `d(10, 3, 4, 2)`

so it is able to return the "last digit" of the result in any base.

Comment: @neilslater answer is much better, based on the observation that we don't need to compute the cycle at each stage, because once we get to the first stage of the exponential, n^4 === n (mod whatever was the previous cycle, including the initial base 10). My answer is able to start say with base 13 instead of 10, where the cycles are much weirder at the first stages.

Comment: Actually `n^5 === n`, not `n^4 === n`

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 7 bytes

```
e.U^Zb_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P1UvNC4qKf7//2hjHSMdk1gA)

Explanation:

```
e.U^Zb_   //full program
 .U       //reduce with the function
   ^Zb    //lambda b,Z:Z^b
      _   //on reversed (implicit) input
e         //return last digit
```

Also, if input can be taken in reverse order, the final _ can be removed for a final score of 6 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org), 37 bytes

```
[ reverse [ swap ^ ] 1reduce 10 mod ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VYo9DoJAFIR7TjGNpUQUE6MHMDY2xopgQpZHNMqCb9_6E0LtIWxo8E7cRiJE4zQz38w8X0mkJOOqeWw3q_VyDkNnS1qR-SWXbsKRQRrJ3k2sVnLItMGRWNPp0yJnErnnfNCCheMUDloVmMDHGGVPfsv_5H1p2m9lbSUZzppBAKYLsSEEMNcoxw4hPKbYKoI3QprFCLtznbaz2-Wq6vwN)

Reverse the input, reduce by swapped exponentiation, take the last digit.

Answer (score 2):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 25 bytes

```arturo
$=>[%do join.with:"^"&10]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?oWR7fS)

```
$=>[                ; a function where input is assigned to &
    join.with:"^"&  ; turn [3 4 2] into "3^4^2", for example
    do              ; eval
    %...10          ; modulo 10
]                   ; end fucntion
```

Answer (score 1):

## ES6, 44 bytes, solves all cases from the original problem

Thanks to @NeilSlater for the (mod 4) condition

```js
a=>a.reduceRight((t,n)=>n<2?n:n**(t%4+4))%10
```

Tested passing an array of 2^20 elements each equal to 2^20

Answer (score 1):

### Perl 5, 22 + 2 (`-pl` flag) = 24 bytes

One-liner:

```
$_=(s/ +/**/g,eval)%10
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lajWF9BW19LSz9dJ7UsMUdT1dDg/39jBRMFIy4TBWMoachlCmL/yy8oyczPK/6vW5ADAA).

Comment: I think you can remove the `+` and require the input string to be single-space separated.

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](http://www.php.net/), 54 bytes

```php
<?eval('echo '.str_replace(',','**',$argv[1]).'%10;');
```

To run it:

```
php -n <filename> <number,number,...>
```

Example:

```
php -n last_digit.php 5,3,2
```

Or [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxj61LDFHQz01OSNfQV2vuKQovii1ICcxOVVDXQcItbTUdVQSi9LLog1jNfXUVQ0NrNU1rf///2@qY6xj9C@/oCQzP6/4v24eAA)

---

## How?

Simply creates a string with format of `<number>**<number>**<number>...%10` and outputs the evaluation of that string.

For input of `5,3,2`, the evaluation string will be `echo 5**3**2%10;`.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 10, 77 bytes (limited to 2<sup>32</sup>-1)

```java
a->{int i=a.length-1,j=a[i];for(;i-->0;)j=(int)Math.pow(a[i],j);return j%10;}
```

Input is an `int[]`, output is an `int`.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jZDPjoIwEMbvPsVcNoFkQPsPs2nwDfTi0XjoImoRC4Gq2RienS24m8Vb02SSTr/ffF@nUHcVFYdLn5WqbWGttHnOALSxeXNUWQ6b4To2IAtc3e1BhdL1upkrrVVWZ7ABA6lT9SpaPQepTlVc5uZkzxHBIlU7vZfHqgmkjqLVQoZFOswK18qe47p6BIMAi1A2ub01BooPspBdLweL@vZVOotfp3ulD3B1KYOtbbQ5jXFeEbffrc2vcXWzce2ebGkCE2eByR8w5n4y5Ei7MJROPJ8DZ7jgCS4p8cM5silOE4qEc3@W/LOJJybeLQl@CjeHCj@aopjSjKEQHDmjvpkpsklmgYIlvpv@A1@rWvphhL5h7ur70fGM7DRpN@v6Hw)

## Java 10, 82 bytes (limited to 2<sup>64</sup>-1)

```java
a->{int i=a.length-1;var j=a[i];for(;i-->0;)j=(long)Math.pow(a[i],j);return j%10;}
```

Input is a `long[]`, output is a `long`.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##lZHNjoIwFIX3PsXdTAJJQfuHmTT4BOjGpXHRQdQyWAhUzITw7ExRJ@PoppM0bfpzvnPubS5bGeS7zyEtZNPAUirdTQCUNlm9l2kGq3ELUJT6AKk3LpstSF/Y035ip8ZIo1JYgYbYvhtksOisGlQswyLTB3MMsGhlDXksN2or9mXtCRUEi5nw8/gK9JfSHMOqvHjjC5T7os7MudaQv@GZ6Acx@lTnj8L63O3aUu3gZMN6a1Ore6Zb0vVXY7JTWJ5NWNkrU2hPh6mnswvc0nc0QSxBJOl9X4yK6RQYRTMWoTnBjgwLoE8MEhGEGfsXAD8CIlctfzXH6J1ThAl3RJAE8ScEpYhzhhgl7iWQMcljCRxxGrn/w6/43sO5oxaTP9JrCwh1L/5nXBmPwftJP3wD)

## Java 10, 177 bytes (unlimited)

```java
a->{int i=a.length-1;var j=a[i];for(;i-->0;){var r=j.ONE;for(var t=a[i];j.signum()>0;t=t.multiply(t),j=j.shiftRight(1))if(j.testBit(0))r=r.multiply(t);j=r;}return j.mod(j.TEN);}
```

Input is a `java.math.BigInteger[]`, output is a `java.math.BigInteger`.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##1ZdNb9tGEIbv/hV7JIERM/u9C0I5BMihhzpA01uQAytLMlmJNqiVi8Dwb3ffoYK0B6MykBhOBcg0d@fjmXdmSXvo7rrFcPXn42rXHQ7q164f7y@U6seynjbdaq0u5VapAXbNvivXzbt@@wt2t@tJraqnlj99Vl3dwuvhAj8u1aiWCPDYLd7eI6zql12zW4/bcr3Q7V03qWHZfeo/t5ubqWr7xeItt/W9rE/Loflw@X7ekPtyshuaQ78dj/uqhmVZlmZ/3JX@dvelKjUN8Dlc95vyW7@9LpWu635TDU1ZH8q7vlRc19Ny@rdHOyyn9mFal@M0qqHZ31zB/Pf3l3X78NgK/@3xj12/UofSFVzubvortYdI1ccy9eN2rvWkkEin9qh1XP8131SzCEp9/HIo631zcyzNLXzKbqz2zdisKjF8WsD7p5abu253XH/YVBZ1/te@O7Nv6oe6btWbN8pZYhcoGv0ypOdI7LNJTTCknfs5MfU3zPBChP6HCakpe0va@JcBNWdA/LNBrSXvHTlrXqfp5qzk35ruydvwOmf9K8W5j5yg@DKE2jyT4SwhIr3OUH7/vghwoX7izz9j@joSn5vj@L@Q0BjyRlMIgXTCe9NmSpop6kCsI56quA94buGd6qIj4yJl42FjKSc/@1jGN1lyiclmT9FnMh6tMYmMCZRyxnoitppM1Kc4sNFRYhqyWpO2CV/4s6HMmWKOZCOTD5LH4UVpKfhIyTF4MtiQx2DNyJMfeTiR8wn2Dux4I1jEzYyckoNnhixfJ4zwZ/B6sUsUhSkgv4Fv9OQ0XszWzfWHDH18IJ/AleCfNCXDM4sFf4B@BjYathF7DnoF5DSIHZLoasmCSePZb6Chx8gaMATkT6jVQXuLehMYUoQt9NQRfEETI2@ArsmjDtj6mUVyJ8pgZAYrtPfoGcM3WMl10kJDI7Ex6Idm9DPINc59k7hs0cN8imFZNAMLep5Qh2WwZEtR9qCjzuhbgBbQ3KB3QWfkRb2oa@6tlplBzxN8YROcsMMff@Cw6Ij6PJiScIveBnOFOdIyc1gPYGboFKFrQv0MrTXmJ0Mb76E7fnfg9eDw0I2NzAhqcpgT6RtqTBFX0R82kSW@owxmBx0NYopuGrqzzAu09phVRo80ZsWCi2UN@XQCI2bWYj495sFqxIE@HER/WTudiezlKvnQDzkHWGfEMnONOEfIKX1i6Grxzk@oG@dh/hfi4fFv)

`java.math.BigInteger` has [a builtin `pow` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#pow(int)), but only accepts `int` as parameter. This last answer uses a golfed variation of [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4582440/1682559) as implementation of a `pow(BigInteger, BigInteger)` method.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `t`, 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
µʋ@
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDMiVCNSVDQSU4QiU0MCZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PSU1QjMlMkMlMjA0JTJDJTIwMiU1RCUyMCUzRCUzRSUyMDElMEElNUI0JTJDJTIwMyUyQyUyMDIlNUQlMjAlM0QlM0UlMjA0JTBBJTVCNCUyQyUyMDMlMkMlMjAxJTVEJTIwJTNEJTNFJTIwNCUwQSU1QjUlMkMlMjAzJTJDJTIwMiU1RCUyMCUzRCUzRSUyMDUmZmxhZ3M9Q3Q=)

##### Explanation

```python
µʋ@  # Implicit input
µʋ   # Right-reduce the list by:
  @  #  Swapped exponentiation
     # Take the last item (digit)
     # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 6 [bytes](https://uiua.org/pad?src=U0JDUyDihpAgK0BcMOKKlwpEZWNvZGUg4oaQIOKHjOKKjy0x4pa9wrEu4o2Y4ouv4oav4oqCwq8x4qe74ouv4qe7LOKHjOKItSjihpjCrzHii68rMjU2KSAtQFwwKzEKJnAg4oqCIjggYml0IGVuY29kaW5nOlx0IiBTQkNTICLih4ziio8tMeKWvcKxLuKNmOKLr-KGr-KKgsKvMeKnu-KLr-Knuyzih4ziiLUo4oaYwq8x4ouvKzI1NikiIOKKgitAXDDih6ExMjkiLiziiLY74oiYwqzCscKv4oy14oia4peL4oyK4oyI4oGFPeKJoDziiaQ-4omlKy3Dl8O34pe_4oG_4oKZ4oan4oal4oig4qe74paz4oeh4oqi4oeM4pmt4ouv4o2J4o2P4o2W4oqa4oqb4oqd4pah4oqU4omF4oqf4oqC4oqP4oqh4oav4oaZ4oaY4oa74per4pa94oyV4oiK4oqXL-KIp1xc4oi14omh4oi64oqe4oqg4o2l4oqV4oqc4oip4oqT4oqD4oqZ4ouF4o2Y4o2c4o2a4qyaJz_ijaPijaQh4o6L4oas4pqCzrfPgM-E4oiefl9bXXt9KCnCr0AkXCLihpB8IyIKJnAg4oqCImRlY29kZWQ6XHQiIERlY29kZSAiwqPCsS0xwrjChy7DjMKlwrPCsMKIMcKfwqXCnyzCo8K_KMK1wogxwqUrMjU2KSIg4oqCK0BcMOKHoTEyOSIuLOKItjviiJjCrMKxwq_ijLXiiJril4vijIrijIjigYU94omgPOKJpD7iiaUrLcOXw7fil7_igb_igpnihqfihqXiiKDip7vilrPih6HiiqLih4zima3ii6_ijYnijY_ijZbiipriipviip3ilqHiipTiiYXiip_iioLiio_iiqHihq_ihpnihpjihrvil6vilr3ijJXiiIriipcv4oinXFziiLXiiaHiiLriip7iiqDijaXiipXiipziiKniipPiioPiipnii4XijZjijZzijZrirJonP-KNo-KNpCHijovihqzimoLOt8-Az4TiiJ5-X1tde30oKcKvQCRcIuKGkHwjIg==)

```
◿10/ⁿ⇌
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=f%20%E2%86%90%20%E2%97%BF10%2F%E2%81%BF%E2%87%8C%0A%0Af%203_4_2%0Af%204_3_2%0Af%204_3_1%0Af%205_3_2)

```
     ⇌  # reverse
   /ⁿ   # reduce by power
◿10     # modulo 10
```

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 34 bytes

```
Prompt A
1
For(I,dim(lA),1,~1
lA(I)^Ans
End
10fPart(.1Ans
```

`~` represents the negative sign.

Answer (score -13):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 19 bytes

```python
lambda N:eval(N)%10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUcHPKrUsMUfDT1PV0OB/QVFmXolGmoaSsYKWloIJiDBS0tT8DwA)

The input is given as a string where each integer is separated by the characters `**`. I claim that the two characters `**` are equally reasonable to `,`  at separating digit sequences.

Comment: 16: `print input()%10`

Comment: -1, because I think the input format is not reasonable. Where to stop? I can take the input as a string representation of a list and declare the list opening as `(`, the list separator as `**` and the list closing as `)%10`. My answer is then a simple eval. Very funny.

Comment: Very similar to [this standard loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14110/78123) (-1)

Comment: [Related meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9506/60043)

Comment: @JungHwanMin Correct me if I am wrong, but I interpret this as such that there currently is no real consensus on allowing borderline input specification like this.

Comment: How about just `join`ing input on `**`?  Adds 11 bytes, but still beats the other python answers: https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUcHPKrUsMUdDSUtLSS8rPzNPw09TU9XQ4H9BUWZeiUaaRrSSsZKOgpIJiDBSitXU/A8A

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Thanks for the suggestion, though I encourage you to post it yourself.

Comment: I don't consider this to violate the loophole linked to above, but don't think this kind of answer should be permitted.